# Ao buscar o atributo de uma tag, está trazendo o valor de outra

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
function returnvalue($namearr,$exec){
    $result="";
    foreach($namearr as $arr => $value) {
        $regex = '<.* name="'. $value .'".*>';
        if (preg_match($regex,$exec,$result1) === false) {
            $result4=" FALSO OFFSET MORE HIGHER THAN SUBJECT " . "<br />";
        } else if (preg_match($regex,$exec,$result1) == 0) {
            $result4=" VOID" . "<br />";
        } else  {
            preg_match('/value="[\w]+"/i',$result1[0],$result2);
            $result3 = preg_replace('/value="/i',"",$result2[0]);
            $result4 = substr($result3,0,-1);
        }
        $result.= $value." : ".$result4 . "<br />";
    }
return $result;
}
```

`$exec` recebe: `<input name="fb_dtsg" value="AQHF4anP9ASw" autocomplete="off" type="hidden">`

`$namearr` recebe: `fb_dtsg`

O código todo acima é para simplesmente retornar o `value` do `input`. Eu já testei com outros `names` (ao invés de `fb_dtsg`, coloquei outro) e me retornou o valor correto.

Acontece que aqui, está retornando algo como: `mag_glass`, na verdade, o retorno esperado é: `AQHF4anP9ASw`. Só que retorna algo totalmente diferente, na verdade, o que retorno nem existe no `$exec`.

Acredito que seja um retorno do `preg_match`, mas procurei saber mais sobre o `mag_glass` e não achei nada.

**Obs1:** *`$exec` recebe mais coisas além do o que mostrei aqui, mas para fins de organização coloquei apenas a parte que importa.*

**Obs2:** *fiz o teste a mão com regexr, para ver se chegava até o valor correto, e chegou, mas nesta função apenas para o `name fb_dtsg` o valor é diferente.*

Comment: Esse *mag_glass* deve existir em alguma outra parte do texto/html que você está analisando. Tem como criar um exemplo funcional disto? Por exemplo no Ideone.

Comment: na verdade sim, seria este: `<input name="init" id="init" value="mag_glass" type="hidden">`, mas descarto possibilidade, já que ele não se encaixa na minha regex..

Comment: minha regex fica essa: `<.* name="fb_dtsg".*>`, para mim, não teria como encaixar, já que o name tem que ser obrigatoriamente aquele definido na regex..

Comment: Ele deve ser válido em algum dos `if`s ou no `else`.

Comment: se válido em qualquer if ou else, ele imprimiria outro valor, mas defato existe o mag_glass como value no documento, mas veja minha regex que postei acima, faria sentido marcar no documento o value como mag_glass?

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja em usar `.*` isso tenta corresponder a qualquer coisa independente do tamanho. Porque não usa somente `name="fb_dtsg"`, ao meu ver o `.*` e `<>` são desnecessários.

Comment: preciso pegar o value do input com name="x", entende? então eu pego o input inteiro que tem o name "x", e depois eu trato ele para chegar até o value..
Faz sentido o que disse, mas ele vai partir de < e vai preencher qualquer coisa até chegar no `name="fb_dtsg"` e depois ele vai continuar, se não existe o name, então o regext retorna 0 já que não foi nada encontrado dentro do que escrevi na regex. Olha, posso estar errado, mas pelo que lembro é, agradeço sua ajuda até agr @Qmechanic73! Vou rever os comentários para ver se chego em alguma conclusão.

Comment: Pelos comentários, observei o que você disse sobre `.*`, realmente eles estavam trazendo um resultado diferente do esperado, eu coloquei no regex e me espantei quando ele pegava uma gigantesca parte do HTML, que ia até o name `fb_dtsg`, mas o value venho o de outro, já que o segundo regex que capturava o value chegava até o primeiro value= que aparece-se(já que eu esperava passar para o 2° regex um input e nao uma grande parte do html da página). 
Agradeço pelo toque, resolvi o problema!

Comment: Ótimo =). Você vai trocar o `.*` por alguma outra expressão?  Se possível poste uma resposta descrevendo como você chegou na solução.

Comment: O objetivo do script acima é capturar o value de qualquer name de um input, então, eu desenvolvi esta regex: `<input[\w "\.;:,\{\}_&\$%"=-]* name="'. $value .'"[\w "\.;:,\{\}_&\$%"=-]*>`, onde `$value` é o name do input que quero descobrir qual o valor do atributo `value`. Este regex atende minhas necessidades, mas para htmls normais dificilmente terá algo no input com `:,&`.. Grato ai!

Comment: Mas você já chegou a uma solução? se não, se for possível poste um trecho do HTML. Utilizar *regex* nesse caso pode trazer resultados bem imprecisos. Eu poderia tentar postar uma resposta usando um parser, ficaria um pouco mais legível o código.

Comment: Cheguei sim, você pode sim me sugestionar o uso do parser, eu tenho uma vaga lembrança mas seria importante para mim você sugestionar desta forma, se ela for mais precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso, há duas soluções: usar regex (mais complicado e menos indicado), ou um *parser* de HTML (mais simples e o mais indicado). Ambas estão detalhadas abaixo.

---

### Regex

O HTML completo não foi colocado, mas baseado nos comentários acima, consegui simular o problema com este exemplo:

```
$namearr = array('name' => 'fb_dtsg');
$html = '<input name="init" id="init" value="mag_glass" type="hidden"><input name="fb_dtsg" value="AQHF4anP9ASw" autocomplete="off" type="hidden">';
echo returnvalue($namearr, $html);
```

Repare que o "HTML" tem duas tags `input`, sendo que a primeira tem o `value="mag_glass"`, e a segunda tem o `name="fb_dtsg"`.

O que acontece é que primeiro você usa `preg_match` para verificar se existe algum `name` igual a "fb_dtsg". No caso, existe, e por isso o código cai no último `else` da função. E dentro deste `else` você chama outro `preg_match` procurando pelo `value`. O problema é que o `preg_match` por *default* sempre começa a verificar desde o início da string (veja a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), especialmente a parte que fala sobre o parâmetro `offset`).

Ou seja, sua função segue esta lógica:

- tem `name="fb_dtsg"` em algum lugar da string?
- se tiver, procura por `value="..."` em algum lugar da string

O problema ocorre se tivermos mais de um `input`, pois os 2 passos acima são independentes, no sentido de que ambos fazem sua busca desde o início da string, sem saber do contexto geral (cada busca acima sai procurando na string pelo trecho que quer, sem saber se este trecho pertence ao mesmo `input` que foi encontrado pelo outro).

---

Sendo assim, uma opção para resolver o problema seria:

```
function returnvalue($namearr,$exec){
    foreach($namearr as $arr => $name) {
        $reg_name = 'name="'. $name .'"';
        $reg_value = 'value="([^"]+)"';
        $regex = "/<input[^>]+(?|{$reg_name}[^>]+{$reg_value}|{$reg_value}[^>]+{$reg_name})/";
        $result = preg_match($regex, $exec, $matches);
        if ($result === false) {
            $value =" FALSO OFFSET MORE HIGHER THAN SUBJECT " . "<br />";
        } else if ($result == 0) {
            $value =" VOID" . "<br />";
        } else {
            $value = $matches[1];
        }
        $result.= $name." : ".$value . "<br />";
    }
    return $result;
}

$namearr = array('name' => 'fb_dtsg');
$html = '<input name="init" id="init" value="mag_glass" type="hidden"><input name="fb_dtsg" value="AQHF4anP9ASw" autocomplete="off" type="hidden">';
echo returnvalue($namearr, $html);
```

Primeiro eu criei duas sub-expressões para o `name` e o `value`. Para o nome, a expressão será `name="nome_que_foi_passado_para_a_função"`. No caso acima, será literalmente `name="fb_dtsg"`.

Para o valor, a expressão é `value="([^"]+)"`. Ou seja, a string `value="`, seguida de `[^"]+`. O trecho `[^"]` é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e no caso significa qualquer caractere que **não** seja `"`. E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, eu quero que o `value="` seja seguido de um ou mais caracteres que não sejam aspas - assim eu pego tudo que tiver ali dentro, menos as aspas de fechamento.

Este trecho está entre parênteses, assim eles formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), cujo valor eu posso recuperar depois, como fiz com `$matches[1]` - como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então é o primeiro grupo de captura, por isso usei o índice 1.

Em seguida, eu monto a regex completa. Repare que em PHP a regex deve ter delimitadores (neste caso, são as barras, mas outros caracteres também são aceitos). Na sua regex você não estava usando as barras, o que quer dizer que os caracteres `<` e `>` estavam funcionando como delimitadores (eles não fazem parte da regex em si - nesse caso "funcionava" por coincidência, mas é importante salientar que os delimitadores só servem para indicar que entre eles tem uma regex, mas eles não fazem parte da expressão em si).

Um detalhe é que a regex possui explicitamente `<input`, pois é a tag que você quer capturar. Ao usar `.*`, você diz que a regex pode pegar qualquer coisa, pois esta expressão significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere".

A regex usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**), para cobrir duas possibilidades: o `name` pode estar tanto antes quanto depois do `value` (já que em HTML eu posso ter esses atributos em qualquer ordem). Sendo assim, a estrutura geral da regex é:

- a string `<input`, seguida de `[^>]+` (um ou mais caracteres que **não** sejam o `>`, assim eu garanto que a regex não "invadirá" outras tags)
- a alternância a seguir segue o formato `(?|name[^>]+value|value[^>]+name)`. Ou seja, o `name` pode estar tanto antes quanto depois do `value`, e entre eles eu tenho `[^>]+` para garantir que a regex não sairá da tag
- eu uso `(?|` que indica um [*branch reset*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html). Fiz isso porque a expressão do `value` tem um grupo de captura, mas como ela aparece duas vezes na regex, isso criaria dois grupos (e eu teria que fazer um `if` para saber se foi o grupo 1 ou 2 que foi encontrado). Mas como cada grupo está em uma das alternativas (e só uma delas pode dar *match* por vez), eu posso usar o *branch reset*, que eles sempre serão o grupo 1.

A saída é:

```
1fb_dtsg : AQHF4anP9ASw<br />
```

Note também que não precisa chamar `preg_match` duas vezes seguidas, como você fez nos dois primeiros `if`'s. Chame uma vez e guarde o retorno, e pronto.

Outro detalhe é que esta regex só dará *match* se o `value` tiver alguma coisa. Caso queira pegar também os casos de `value=""`, basta trocar o `+` por `*`:

```
$reg_value = 'value="([^"]*)"';
```

Pois o asterisco significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências".

---

### Parser de HTML

Usar regex para fazer *parsing* de HTML [não é o ideal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052)). Para casos mais simples, pode até funcionar (mesmo que neste caso, embora o HTML seja simples, a regex não é), mas neste caso eu acho bem mais simples usar uma API específica para HTML, como por o exemplo o [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Veja como ficaria para encontrar os `input`'s:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$name = "fb_dtsg";
foreach($xpath->query('//input[@name="'. $name. '"]') as $input){
    echo $input->getAttribute('value');
}
```

No caso, ele procura todos os campos `input` que possuem o nome indicado, e pegam o seu respectivo valor.

Esta solução não só é mais simples, como também trata de vários casos que a regex acima deixa passar.

Por exemplo, se o `input` estiver dentro de comentários:

```html
<!--
<input name="fb_dtsg" value="AQHF4anP9ASw" autocomplete="off" type="hidden">
-->
```

Nesse caso, a regex encontra o *match* mesmo assim ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/1Vupao/1/)), já o `DOMDocument` ignora os comentários corretamente. E fazer uma regex para detectar se o `input` está dentro de um comentário é bem complicada (você teria que juntar a regex acima com algo parecido com [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42097865), por exemplo) e na minha opinião não vale a pena.