# Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?

Tags: html, regex

Eu entendo que se eu tentar utilizar Regex sobre HTML, [as tags HTML vão escorrer de meus olhos como dor líquida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2263584), dentre outros horrores. E que eu deveria utilizar um parser de XML ou algo do tipo.

Meu lado criança curioso não para de me perguntar: mas por que? Por que, caro Stack Overflow, não posso eu usar expressões regulares para garimpar nos campos das linguagens de marcação?

Comment: Porque RegEx faz xixi na calça :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## TL;DR

O HTML é simplesmente **mais complexo** do que *Regex*, a ponto que é impossível ter uma Expressão Regular que trate o HTML de maneira satisfatória.

## Explicação

A explicação mais direta está na **[linguagem formal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_formal)** com ajuda da
***[Hierarquia de Chomsky](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarquia_de_Chomsky)***, a qual basicamente organiza as linguagens de acordo com sua complexidade, isto é, liberdade de regras e máquina reconhecedora da linguagem.

Do **Tipo 0**, a mais complexa - que gera todas as gramáticas reconhecíveis pela Máquina de Turing, ao **Tipo 3**, a menos complexa, reconhecível por um simples autômato finito.

- *Regex* ou **Expressão Regular** é a implementação da **Gramática Regular**, do Tipo 3 da Hierarquia de *Chomsky*, sendo uma gramática linear, reconhecida facilmente por um **autômato finito**.
- Já o **HTML** deriva do SGML, o qual é uma **Linguagem Livre de Contexto** (LLC), gerada por uma **Gramática Livre de Contexto** (GLC), do Tipo 2, reconhecida por um **autômato com pilha**. E o HTML nem LLC é, apesar de ser *Turing Complete* pela *Regra 110* em combinação com o CSS3.

Isto é, um autômato finito **não** é o suficiente para reconhecer a HTML, sendo preciso um autômato com pilha para reconhecer o SGML, que gerou o HTML. Assim, por definição não é possível reconhecer o HTML com Expressão Regular de modo satisfatório (que cobre todos os casos).

---

***Notas:***

1. A Gramáticas na Hierarquia de *Chomsky* não estão mutual-exclusivamente separadas e sim, por postas em subconjuntos: Tipo #0 ⊊ #1 ⊊ #2 ⊊ #3.

Comment: HTML não é livre de contexto? Tem como por a referência desse _regra 110_?

Comment: Achei uma referência: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110 ; Jogo da VIda de Conway =)

Comment: Eu sabia disso para CSS3 junto com HTML, não HTML _per si_. E também tem o ponto que a descrição em si é GLC (mesmo que a computação dessa descrição permita algo Turing Completo). Por exemplo, eu escrevi um identificador de linguagens Tipo 0 usando apenas GLC, [nessa resposta sobre Meta Linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215974/64969)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado HTML per se, não - por definição. Corrigi o texto. Porém, HTML não é livre de contexto (apesar de haver alguns defensores dessa ideia, equivocadamente ao meu ver). Não vou me aprofundar nesse tópico aqui porque ele não é pertinente ao post, mas há bastante material na internet.

Answer (score 12):

Como André Figueiredo explicou perfeitamente, expressões regulares (no sentido formal do termo) não são poderosas o suficiente para tratar linguagens livres de contexto. Por isso, tratar HTML com regexes não é uma boa prática.

Uma explicação mais prática pode ser útil.

## Às vezes a linguagem *não* é HTML

Expressões regulares são úteis para parsear texto, mesmo que o conteúdo seja HTML. Considere uma lista como a abaixo:

```
<ul class="my-list">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

É fácil pegar o conteúdo de cada item com uma expressão regular (exemplo em Python):

```
>>> a = '''<ul class="my-list">
...   <li>item1</li>
...   <li>item2</li>
...   <li>item3</li>
... </ul>'''
>>> def items(string):
...     return re.findall('<li>(.*)</li>', string)
... 
>>> items(a)
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

Isto não é "errado" *per se*. É bastante prático, aliás. No caso, não queremos nem tratar uma linguagem livre de contexto como HTML. Queremos apenas tratar a linguagem regular `<li>.*</li>`.

## Aí a linguagem se transforma em HTML

O (potencial) problema com essa abordagem é que o conteúdo pode mudar de maneiras que uma regex não pode acompanhar.

Digamos que o HTML é gerado por uma aplicação dinâmica, e um dia ele muda para algo assim:

```
<ul class="my-list">
    <li>
        item1
    </li>
    <li>
        item2
        <ol class="sublist">
            <li>item2.1</li>
            <li>item2.2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        item3
    </li>
</ul>
```

O resultado será bem diferente agora:

```
>>> b = '''<ul class="my-list">
...     <li>
...         item1
...     </li>
...     <li>
...         item2
...         <ol class="sublist">
...             <li>item2.1</li>
...             <li>item2.2</li>
...         </ol>
...     </li>
...     <li>
...         item3
...     </li>
... </ul>'''
>>> items(b)
['item2.1', 'item2.2']
```

Algumas partes do problema são fáceis de resolver. Podemos alterar a expressão para incluir `item1` e `item3` ao descartar espaços em branco, como em `<li>\s*(.*)\s*</li>`. Outras são mais complicadas. Como pegar `item2`? Queremos pegar a sub-lista em `item2`, ou apenas o texto? Se quisermos pegar apenas os items da primeira lista, como fazemos?

É aí que expressões regulares começam falham. É praticamente impossível fazer a expressão regular entender que está no primeiro nível, ou no segundo, por exemplo.

Esse cenário é comum: uma solução simples com regex começa a falhar em um caso, depois em outro, depois outro... Aos poucos vai sendo adaptada,  mas a regex fica cada vez mais complicada. Com o tempo, ela fica quase impossível de entender.

## A solução através do parser

Um parser HTML é ligeiramente mais complicado de usar que uma expressão regular, mas é muito mais poderoso.

Por exemplo, nossa função poderia utilizar [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) ao invés de expressões regulares. Seria algo assim:

```
>>> def items(string)
...     b = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
...     items = b.find_all('li')
...     return [i.text for i in items]
... 
>>> items(a)
[u'item1', u'item2', u'item3']
```

Tem mais código aqui, mas não muito. Agora, o que acontece se chamamos essa função com o novo valor `b`?

```
>>> items(b)
[u'\n        item1\n    ', u'\n        item2\n        \nitem2.1\nitem2.2\n\n', u'item2.1', u'item2.2', u'\n        item3\n    ']
```

Dessa vez, ela retornou o conteúdo de todos os `li`!

Por outro lado, ela falhou também, de maneira diferente. Mas é mais fácil consertar agora. Para remover os espaços em branco, usamos o método `strip()`:

```
>>> def items(string):
...     b = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
...     elements = b.find_all('li')
...     return [e.text.strip() for e in elements]
... 
>>> items(b)
[u'item1', u'item2\n        \nitem2.1\nitem2.2', u'item2.1', u'item2.2', u'item3']
```

A lista aninhada é adicionada como texto no `item2`. Felizmente, o parser é *flexível*: podemos usar o método `find()` de cada elemento para pegar apenas texto:

```
>>> def items(string):
...     b = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
...     elements = b.find_all('li')
...     return [e.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip() for e in elements]
... 
>>> items(b)
[u'item1', u'item2', u'item2.1', u'item2.2', u'item3']
```

Se queremos apenas os items da lista primária, podemos ser mais específicos. Vamos pegar a lista primeiro, e então vamos pegar todos os `<li>` dela, sem recursividade:

```
>>> def items(string):
...     b = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
...     list = b.find('ul')
...     elements = list.find_all('li', recursive=False)
...     return [e.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip() for e in elements]
... 
>>> items(b)
[u'item1', u'item2', u'item3']
```

A função não é tão simples quanto a primeira, mas faz muito mais coisas. E, melhor ainda, pudemos evoluí-la gradativamente, de maneira legível.

## Uma só ferramenta boa versus a melhor ferramenta para o trabalho

Isto *não* significa que nunca se possa usar expressões regulares para extrair conteúdo de HTML. A questão são os tradeoffs:

- Se você está fazendo um script descartável, expressão regular é provavelmente uma boa escolha;
- Se você confia que o formato do HTML não vai mudar, a expressão regular pode ser suficiente;
- Se você tem controle sobre o HTML a ser tratado, e estiver disposto a usar um formato rígido nele (o que não é uma boa ideia), a expressão regular será estável;
- Se você estiver disposto para correr e alterar sua regex toda vez que alguem mudar alguma coisa no HTML, você pode fazê-lo (e se preparar para perder batante tempo.)

É muito fácil um principiante fascinar-se com a simplicidade das expressões regulares e fazer a escolha errada. Por isso, é tão comum recomendar que se use o parser desde a primeira linha de código. O parser é sempre *uma escolha certa*, e 90% das vezes é *a escolha mais certa*.

Agora, se você é experiente e já está acostumado com parsers, pode pesar os prós e contras caso a caso. No final das contas, mesmo que expressão regular não seja a escolha mais escalável, se você a mantiver encapsulada em uma função vai ser bem fácil substituí-la por um parser eventualmente.

Comment: Tipo _parsear_ Java? Dá pra fazer algumas coisas com regex https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214947/64969