# Percorrer conteúdo HTML e remover partes do HTML usando PHP

Tags: php

Tenho por exemplo esse código que remove todas as `DIVs` que contenham a classe `contextual` do meu código `HTML` passado na string `$sHTML`:

```
$nPosIni = strpos($sHTML, '<div class="contextual">');
while ($nPosIni > 0) { // remove todas as divs com a classe contextual
    $nPosFim = strpos($sHTML, '</div>', $nPosIni);
    $sHTML = substr($sHTML, 0, $nPosIni) . 
             substr($sHTML, ($nPosFim + strlen("</div>")));
    $nPosIni = strpos($sHTML, '<div class="contextual">');
}
```

Logo, o que eu preciso é remover de um código `HTML` uma outra `<div>` com outra classe, porém quero que permaneça apenas um `<h3> CONTEÚDO </h3>` que tem dentro dessa `<div>`.

---

Tentei de diversas maneiras mas não consegui achar uma maneira eficiente, alguém sabe de alguma boa prática?

---

*OBS.: O código que estou usando não aceita scripts nem functions, só `PHP`, `HTML` e `CSS` ...*

---

**HTML DE EXEMPLO:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="xy">
            <h3> conteúdo </h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HTML COMO DEVE FICAR:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h3> conteúdo </h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já tentou algo com a classe DOMDocument?

Comment: Você pode fornecer cópia do código html que serve de base para esta rotina?

Comment: Quer que permaneça a div caso tenha o h3? Ou remova a div e mantenha o elemento h3 que tinha dentro?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, não tentei, como sugere?

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt, Quero remover toda DIV e deixar só o H3 que tinha dentro.

Comment: @CaiubyFreitas, acredito que o código não é necessário, pois serviria para qualquer tipo de código ...

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo na pergunta do código HTML, como está e como deverá ficar?

Comment: Claro, só um momento...

Comment: Pergunta atualizada, é bem direto mesmo, coloquei apenas um exemplo do uso que preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentei, a melhor forma de se manipular HTML com PHP é utilizando as classes nativas de [DOM](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php). Neste caso, diretamente utilizei as classes `DOMDocument` e `DOMXPath`. O código está comentado quando aos passos executados e acho que será fácil entendê-lo:

```
<?php

$html = <<<HTML
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="xy">
            <h3> conteúdo </h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

// 1. Cria uma instância de DOMDocument:
$dom = new DOMDocument();

// 2. Carrega o código HTML a partir de uma string:
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// 3. Cria uma instância de DomXPath:
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// 4. Busca no HTML todos os elementos `div` que possuem a classe `xy`:
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[@class='xy']");

// 5. Percorre a lista de elementos encontrados:
foreach ($nodes as $node) {

    // 6. Busca o primeiro elemento `h3` dentro da `div`:
    $h3 = $node->getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];

    // 7. Substitui no HTML a `div` pelo respectivo `h3`:
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($h3, $node);
}

// 8. Exibe o HTML final:
echo $dom->saveHTML(), PHP_EOL;
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MMxC/1)</sup>

Comment: Existe uma maneira de salvar a modificação na variável sem exibir com o `echo` ?

Comment: Sim, só fazer a variável receber o valor retornado por `$dom->saveHTML()`.

Comment: Perfeito, muito bom Anderson, funcionou perfeitamente. Legal essa maneira de usar o `Dom`, não conhecia, bem prático. Só por curiosidade, o que faz o `PHP_EQL` no final ?

Comment: É uma constante do PHP: *end of line*, apenas para inserir a quebra de linha. O valor dela é referente ao `\n` ou `\r\n` dependendo do sistema operacional.

Comment: Entendi, não conhecia, então sempre que for preciso usar um `\n` ou `\r\n` é melhor usar o `PHP_EQL` pois será melhor interpretado, ou depende do caso!?

Comment: Se sua aplicação for rodar em diferentes sistemas operacionais, é melhor utilizar a constante.

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer a substituição da div usando a função **preg_replace_callback()** e deixando só a tag h3.

```
$new_sHTML = preg_replace_callback('/<div class=\"xy\">.*?<\/div>/sim',
  function($match) {
    preg_match('/<h3.*?<\/h3>/sim', $match[0], $h3);
    return $h3[0];
  }, $sHTML
);
```

Segue o exemplo funcionando no https://repl.it/MMxC/3

Comment: Desculpa Filipe, mas não funcionou dessas maneiras, nesse segundo método pelo que eu entendi seria para remover toda `<div>`, mas eu preciso que fique o `<h3>` que tem dentro dessa `<div>` em questão, mas mesmo assim não funcionou também, pois o código que estou usando não aceita `functions` também. ':D

Comment: Eu respondi em cima do que você tinha publicado anteriormente, a pergunta não estava com esse detalhamento todo de agora. :(

Comment: Só foi acrescentado o exemplo e ao testar o seu código vi que não funcionava as functions também, daí acrescentei à pergunta.

Comment: Eu não tinha pontuação suficiente para fazer comentários, sou novo, mas tudo bem. Você já conseguiu resolver o problema.

Comment: Certo Filipe, mas agradeço igual a sua contribuição. Apesar de não ser uma boa prática, sugiro que então, remova sua pergunta, para tentar não perder seus pontos, ou edite a mesma com alguma outra idéia ou sugestão.

Comment: Olá Marcos, eu fiz as alterações na minha reposta, ela segue basicamente o que eu havia proposto, porém, entendendo melhor o seu problema, consegui fazer ela cumprir o objetivo, aparentemente. Abraços.

Comment: @FilipeRicardo Talvez seja interessante você ler [Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/5878) para referências futuras.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss legal, vou ler sim, valeu pela dica.

Comment: O bom da programação é que existem diferentes meios de se chegar ao mesmo objetivo, e quanto mais conhecimento, melhor ficamos nessa tomada de decisão, visando sempre o caminho mais curto, ou o melhor a ser seguido.