# No PHP como limitar busca com regex a uma classe div html?

Tags: php

No php, como montar um regex (para usar com o `preg_match_all`) o link no `href` e o título entre `>(.*?)<`  SOMENTE na `class "container"` (15 ocorrências). No source, sem a limitação a uma classe são 60 ocorrências encontradas. 
Sei que usar Regex com html não é recomendado, ocorre que acho regex mais prático de montar. Li no stackoverflow em inglês uma sugestão para capturar o bloco dentro da tag, tentei replicar separando link e titulo, mas não deu certo.

```
<div class="container">
<li class="nav-item cat-item-19"><a href="http://www.exemplo.com/1">teste</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Talvez seja interessante você ler: [Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, sim eu tinha lido na versão americana.  Para ser honesto esse é o meu primeiro entrave real com regex em html. Sempre capturo os dados sem problemas. Só queria saber se - com regex - seria possível fazer essa limitação.