# Web Crawler buscando texto específico na página

Tags: python, web-crawler, crawling

Bem, estou fazendo um web crawler para buscar o valor de uma moeda.

Escrevi o seguinte código em python:

```
#coding: utf-8

from urllib2 import urlopen

conteudo = urlopen('http://dolarhoje.com/bitcoin').read()

procurar1 = '<span class="symbol">'
posicao1 = int(conteudo.index(procurar1) + len(procurar1))
moeda1 = conteudo[posicao1 : posicao1 + 3]

procurar2 = '<span class="symbol">'
posicao2 = int(conteudo.index(procurar2) + len(procurar2))
moeda2 = conteudo[posicao2 : posicao2 + 3]

procurar3 = '<input type="text" id="nacional" value="'
posicao3 = int(conteudo.index(procurar3) + len(procurar3))
valor = conteudo[posicao3 : posicao3 + 8]

print(moeda1 + ' 1,00 ' + 'vale ' + moeda2 + ' ' + valor)
print ('\n')
```

Sei que quando coloco: `procurar1 = '<span class="symbol">'` e utilizo: `conteudo.index(procurar1)` ele vai me retornar a primeira incidência, porém eu gostaria de chamar a **segunda** incidência.

O código executado vai retornar:
`฿ 1,00 vale ฿ 25086,77`

O esperado:
`฿ 1,00 vale R$ 25086,77`

Ou seja, retornar tanto o símbolo da primeira moeda quanto o símbolo da segunda moeda, pegando apenas a segunda incidência por similaridade do código da página.

Como fazer?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi, o valor em real está dentro de um `<span class="cotMoeda nacional">`. Por que você não procura por ela primeiro? Fora isso, acho que por Expressão Regular ia ser mais fácil https://tableless.com.br/o-basico-sobre-expressoes-regulares/

Comment: Ou melhor ainda, dê uma olhada nesse post falando sobre um `parser` próprio: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245947/57474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar do tempo, à fim de fechar esta pergunta com uma solução, é simples se utilizarmos algumas bibliotecas específicas para tal.

### Bibliotecas

- `urllib.request`: responsável por capturar o `html` da página;
- `re`: biblioteca para se usar expressões regulares.

### Explicação de Código

Para capturar o conteúdo usei o seguinte trecho:

```
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://dolarhoje.com/bitcoin').read().decode('utf-8')
```

Estou atribuindo dentro da variável `html_content` o conteúdo do `html` da página para consumir posteriormente, o `read()` faz a leitura, `decode('utf-8')` é para evitar que o site seja capturando em outros padrões de acentuação, as vezes isso acontece.

Ao analisar, podemos ver que há um padrão onde o símbolo das moedas é mostrado dentro presente de uma `tag` `html` como por exemplo:

```
<span class="symbol">฿</span>
<span class="symbol">R$</span>
```

Assim, podemos construir uma expressão regular para capturar as incidências dos símbolos, sendo representado pelo seguinte trecho:

```
symbols = re.findall(r'\"symbol\">([\S]+)</', html_content)
```

`re` estamos usando a biblioteca logo importada no começo do código;

`findall()` é uma função para capturar em forma de uma lista, as incidências;

`r'...'` é onde colocamos a respectiva expressão regular;

Assim, a `regex` construída sobre `\"symbol\">([\S]+)</` captura os símbolos e apresenta-as na seguinte lista: `['฿', 'R$']`

Enquanto `value=\"([.\d,]+)\"` captura os valores e apresenta: `['1,00', '13583,42']`

`html_content` é a respectiva variável onde desejamos encontrar a incidência - ou como dizemos quando usamos `regex` de `match`.

E, usamos o print `print('{0} {1} vale {2} {3}'.format(symbols[0], values[0], symbols[1], values[1]))` para mostrar os respectivos valores usando o `format()`, obtendo assim o resulto desejado:

`฿ 1,00 vale R$ 13583,42`

### Script completo

Abaixo segue o `script` completo:

```
# !/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# começando com os imports
import urllib.request
import re

# capturando o conteúdo html
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://dolarhoje.com/bitcoin').read().decode('utf-8')

# pegando os símbolos das moedas
symbols = re.findall(r'\"symbol\">([\S]+)</', html_content)

# pegando os valores das moedas
values = re.findall(r'value=\"([.\d,]+)\"', html_content)

# mostrando em console o resultado parecido com: '฿ 1,00 vale R$ 13583,42'
print('{0} {1} vale {2} {3}'.format(symbols[0], values[0], symbols[1], values[1]))
```

Espero que esta solução ajude outras pessoas que possam estar com uma dúvida parecida.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer mais facilmente com a biblioteca MechanicalSoup  (https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup)

Para usar basta instalar no seu ambiente: pip install MechanicalSoup

Para pegar o valor que você quer é bem simples:

```
import mechanicalsoup


browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("http://dolarhoje.com/bitcoin")

page = browser.get_current_page()

symbols = page.select(".symbol")
inputs = page.find_all("input")

moeda1 = { 'symbol': symbols[0].text, 'value': inputs[0].attrs['value'] }
moeda2 = { 'symbol': symbols[1].text, 'value': inputs[1].attrs['value'] }

print(moeda1)
print(moeda2)
```