# Regex - Remover entre tag e começo de nome de classe e último fechamento de tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Eu tenho uma string (html) e preciso remover tudo que está entre a primeira ocorrência de `<div class="c` e primeiro fechamento da tag `>` e último fechamento da "`</div>`". O primeiro, deve ser dessa forma pois a classe dessa div é gerada dinamicamente, permanecendo apenas o primeiro caractere.

Por exemplo: `<div class="c2029" style="font-size:45px"><p class="auto">Testando 123...</p></div>` deverá ser transformado em `<p class="auto">Testando 123...</p>`

Tentei da seguinte forma, mas está removendo toda a string:

```
var testString = '<div class="c2029" style="font-size:45px"><p class="auto">Testing 123...</p></div>'
var result = testString.replace(/\<div\_c.*\>/, '');
```

#### Editado

Caso a string tenha uma quebra de linha, a solução deixa de funcionar:

```js
var testString = `<div class="c892"><h3>Título teste</h3>
Descrição após quebra de linha.</div>`
var result = testString.replace(/<div class="c.*?>(.*?)<\/div>/, '$1');

console.log(result);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/086rvvkv/)

Como o Pedro havia informado na própria resposta, era só adicionar `[\s\S]` tendo o seguinte resultado:

```
var result = testString.replace(/<div class="c.*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/, '$1');
```

Comment: Leia o comentário do Anderson Woss [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/270960/75104), em que o recomendado é usar DOM para HTML parsing e não Regex.

Comment: @danieltakeshi então, estou tentando remover apenas essa div e manter todo o conteúdo interno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar de sabermos muito bem qual é a [resposta clássica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) para as pessoas que tentam processar HTML utilizando expressões regulares, também temos a [resposta seguinte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/4262446) na mesma pergunta, que adiciona um ponto interessante.

Para casos pontuais onde eu preciso extrair ou trabalhar algum dado de maneira simples em um texto HTML, muitas vezes é bem mais rápido e prático produzir uma expressão regular que faça o trabalho por mim do que utilizar um parser de HTML. Não vejo problema em usar regex nesse tipo de situação.

Esclarecido isso, a resposta:

```js
var testString = '<div class="c2029" style="font-size:45px"><p class="auto">Testing 123...</p></div>'
var result = testString.replace(/<div class="c.*?>(.*?)<\/div>/, '$1');

console.log(result);
```

A expressão regular em si:

```
<div class="c.*?>(.*?)<\/div>
```

**Explicação:**

- `<div class="c.*?>` - Aqui é utilizado um *lazy quantifier* (`.*?`) para capturar o padrão inicial e parar na primeira ocorrência do fechamento da tag `>`.
- `(.*?)<\/div>` - Utilizamos novamente o *lazy quantifier* em um grupo de captura e terminamos com a tag de fechamento da `div`.
- Por último, utilizamos o `replace()` mantendo o grupo 1 obtido na captura, utilizando o marcador `$1`.

## Atualização

De acordo com o OP, parece que a resposta desejada era outra, já que existem situações onde a `<div>` de fechamento não aparece (o que não foi especificado na pergunta).

**Solução 2:**

```
<div class="c.*?>(((?!<\/div>)[\s\S])*)(<\/div>)?
```

Essa expressão regular foi ajustada para que pudesse considerar a nova situação e também a possibilidade de quebras de linha.

**Demonstração:** [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Q74KYY/1)

**Explicação:**

- `<div class="c.*?>` - Esse é o início da captura do padrão especificado. captura qualquer texto até o fechamento da tag `>`.
- `(((?!<\/div>)[\s\S])*)` - Esse já é um truque um pouco mais complexo. O padrão `(?!<\/div>)` é um *lookahead* que verifica se o match anterior não está seguido do padrão `<\/div>`. Em seguida eu capturo o próximo caractere que é e não um espaço em branco (dado pelo padrão `[\s\S]`), ou seja, qualquer caractere após essa asserção. É necessário verificar primeiro e capturar depois, porque se fosse o contrário (`[\s\S](?!<\/div>)`), o último caractere antes do padrão que não deve ser capturado também não seria capturado (Você pode verificar como isso ocorre alterando a demonstração do regex101). No fim, eu coloquei isso em um grupo de captura e mandei repetir o mesmo padrão zero ou mais vezes, resultando em: `(((?!<\/div>)[\s\S])*)`.
- `(<\/div>)?` - Finalmente, eu capturo o padrão de fechamento da `div`, marcando ele como opcional com o quantificador `?`. Dessa forma, mesmo se o fechamento não existir, não vai haver problema algum.

Comment: dizem que deus chora quando um programador usa Regex para parsear um html...

Comment: Dizem, ainda, que há uma passagem oculta no livro dos Provérbios: "_O homem perverso processa HTML com regex, mas o reto considera a utilização de um parser. Não há sabedoria, nem inteligência, nem mesmo conselho a favor daqueles que blasfemam contra o Senhor lendo linguagens livres de contexto com gramáticas regulares_".

Comment: @Pedro saberia me dizer o por que não funciona quando há algum "\n" dentro dessa div?

Comment: É que o `.` em regex não inclui caracteres de quebra de linha e tabulações. Se você quiser que o seu regex funcione com esses caracteres, substitua o `(.*?)` por `([\s\S]*?)`. Isso vai capturar qualquer caractere possível, incluindo esses que eu mencionei.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9w60cz0v/1/ parece que não funciona

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe Seu exemplo não funciona porque não existe a tag de fechamento da `div` na string. Veja novamente: https://jsfiddle.net/9w60cz0v/2/

Comment: @Pedro sim eu entendo, porém foge do contexto da pergunta, que havia o fechamento da div

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe Não entendi. Se a situação que você acabou de comentar foge ao contexto da pergunta, então por que desmarcou a minha resposta? Afinal, ela respondeu a pergunta original.

Comment: @Pedro me desculpe, buguei totalmente kkkk agora que estou vendo você estava certo. Tava há tanto tempo tentando resolver essa questão que já nem sabia mais o que estava lendo e fazendo

Comment: @Pedro amigo, sei que é antiga essa questão, mas cheguei à outro obstáculo. Se puder me ajudar, estarei editando a pergunta.Obrigado

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe Posso ajudar, sim. Qual é o novo problema?

Comment: @Pedro obrigado, estava na sua resposta já a minha outra pergunta :) editei minha pergunta com a resposta