# Expressão Regular no PHP (Remover uma TAG específica entre outras TAGs)

Tags: php, regex

Preciso aprender a remover a TAG `'</div>'` entre as TAGs `'</blockquote> </div> </figure>'` em PHP.
Reforçando, apenas nessa condição que a TAG `</div>` deverá ser removida.
Como devo proceder?
Obrigado

Comment: Favor ler [Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/75104) ou [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273545/75104) se achar que ainda vai utilizar Regex. Mas não é recomendado para parsing, mas sim para casos muito específicos...

Comment: um simples str_replace nao ajudaria ?

Comment: Não.. O str_replace não funciona não.