# Copiar trecho de código, modificar e colar em outra Div

Tags: javascript, html, regex, html-tags

estou estruturando um sistema experimental onde ao clicar em um botão ele copia o que estiver selecionado (no caso um trecho em html) como o abaixo:

```html
<section>
  <h1> titulo </h1>
  <p>texto desta área</p>
</section>

<button>Modificar código</button>
```

Em seguida ele faria uma alteração no código inserindo as tags que precisam ser inseridas (para minha necessidade)

```html
[[bloco]]
    [[repetir]]
    <section>
      <h1> titulo </h1>
      <p>texto desta área</p>
    </section>
    [[/repetir]]
[[/bloco}}
```

Precisarei usar regex? Existe alguma maneira de se fazer isso apenas copiando o conteúdo, alterando e colando sem precisar utilizar regex?

Comment: Já tem parte do código pronto? Ajudaria se postasse; Visto que vc vai alterar "antes" e "depois" do código copiado, bastaria concatenar o conteúdo: `textoAntes + textoCopiado + textoDepois`.

Comment: Favor ler [Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/75104). Se for uma estrutura html muito específica, pode ser utilizado o Regex. Mas se for para generalizar para vários sites, não é recomendado.

Comment: document.getelementby...().hinnerhtml ajuda você a copiar, tem é de colocar um id ou class na tag que pretende. Depois disso, os "..." substitui por id ou classname e nos () coloca o nome do id ou class.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples de copiar codigo é usando `innerHTML` mas seria necessário algo de fora para apanhar esse bocado de código, por exemplo:

```
<div id="copiarConteudo">
 <section>
  <h1> titulo </h1>
  <p>texto desta área</p>
 </section>
</div>
```

Neste caso bastava:

```
<button onclick="Copia();">Copiar</button>
<script>
  function Copia(){
    var codigo = document.getElementById("copiarConteudo").innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```