# REGEX - Permitir HTML no começo da string

Tags: regex, asp

Essa expressão está cortando o HTML só quando coloco no início da expressão. Como corrigir isso?

```
(?:[ \t]*[a-z][)]\s*)?([^\r\n<]+(?:(?:\r?\n(?!\s*[a-z][)])|<(?!br\s*\/?>(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>)*\s*(?:\s+[a-z][)]|\s*$)))[^\r\n<]*)*)(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*
```

https://regexr.com/3q1ph

```
questao=Request.Form("questao")

'RegEx
Set re = New RegExp
re.Global = true
re.IgnoreCase = true
re.Pattern = "(?:[ \t]*[a-z][)]\s*)?([^\r\n<]+(?:(?:\r?\n(?!\s*[a-z][)])|<(?!br\s*\/?>(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>)*\s*(?:\s+[a-z][)]|\s*$)))[^\r\n<]*)*)(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*"

Set matches = re.Execute(questao)
If (matches.Count) Then

    'PERGUNTA

    pergunta=(matches(0).SubMatches(0)) 
    Response.Write(pergunta)

    'RESPOSTAS
    For m = 1 To matches.Count - 1
        Response.Write(matches(m).SubMatches(0))
        resposta_a=matches(1).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_b=matches(2).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_c=matches(3).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_d=matches(4).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_e=matches(5).SubMatches(0)
    Next
End If

Set matches = Nothing
Set re = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: [Tem certeza que quer tratar HTML com regex?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/5878)

Comment: Talvez tenha me expressado errado. Quero incluir o "<" do strong na expressão. Veja que ele se encontra de fora.

Comment: Mas qual é o objetivo da REGEX? Talvez exista uma solução mais simples.

Comment: Essa expressão separa a pergunta e todas as respostas (a,b,c,d,e), depois vou dar um insert no banco, porém quando, por exemplo formato a primeira palavra dela, o começo do htlm ("<") é cortado. Entendeu?

Comment: Coloque o texto em está a ser aplicado a regex aqui na pergunta, para que seja mais claro o seu objetivo. E detalhe também o que neste momento apanha para o que você queria que apanhasse. Quanto mais detalhar mais probabilidade tem de encontrar uma resposta satisfatória.

Comment: @Isac Tem um link na pergunta que vai direto para expressão e texto tudo montado. Se clicar nele vai entender.

Comment: Eu vi o link, mas não invalida o que eu disse. Não só tenho de abrir um link numa nova página, para tentar adivinhar o que você está a tentar capturar, e consequentemente adivinhar o que não ficou correto. Quanto mais clarificar melhores resultados obtêm.

Comment: @Isac tá ok amigo, me desculpe.

Comment: Essas perguntas vêm de um banco de dados relacional? Porque se vierem acho que essa ideia de juntar as questões em pergunta tudo no mesmo campo é uma estratégia ruim de como o banco foi planejado, eu pessoalmente faria uma tabela para as perguntas relacionada a uma tabela para as opções, assim em caso de remover opções ou edita-las não iria precisar ficar fazendo "parser" com regex

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é justamente o contrário do que está dizendo. Eu pego a pergunta inteira, jogo em um editor tipo fckeditor, formato ela, separo com REGEX e insiro no banco em campos separados. Essa é minha ideia. campo_pergunta, resposta_1, resposta_2 e por ai vai.

Comment: @Rod esta era a intenção mesmo, mas não acho invalido tentar recorrer a isto, eu tenho até uma sugestão talvez eu formule uma resposta amanhã.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está neste primeiro conjunto de negação que exclui o símbolo `<` (bem como o *carriage return* `\r` e o *line feed* `\n`):

```
                             ↓
(?:[ \t]*[a-z][)]\s*)?([^\r\n<]+ ...
```

Basta retirar o `<` que irá funcionar, mas tenho a impressão de esse regex está poluído. Com apenas `([^\r\n])+` já captura tudo em grupos:

```js
string = '<strong>Acerca</strong> dos atos notariais é correto afirmar:\n'
+'\r'
+'a) O testamento público não pode ser celebrado por relativamente incapaz maior de 16 e menor de 18 anos, sem a participação de assistente.\n'
+'b) Não é possível a lavratura de pacto antenupcial no regime da separação parcial de bens, mesmo quando os noivos pretendam alterar ou disciplinar algum aspecto específico do regime de bens, pois esta avença descaracterizaria preceito de ordem pública\n'
+'c) O aspecto temporal da emissão do documento é o critério essencial na diferenciação entre traslado e certidão\n'
+'d) Os requisitos formais a serem observados pelo Tabelião nas escrituras públicas e nas atas notariais são exatamente os mesmos, pois não há diferenças extrínsecas entre estes instrumentos públicos.\n'
+'e) Os requisitos formais a serem osasabservados pelo Tabelião nas escrituras públicas e nasasas atas notariais são exatamente os mesmos, pois não há diferenças extrínsecas entre estsases instrumentos <strong>públicos.</strong>'

matches = string.match(/([^\r\n])+/g)

for(var item of matches){
   console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: A questão é lançada em um fckeditor e esse essa negação "<" tira todo <br /> do fim das respostas que é gerado. Retirando ele funcionou como vc disse, mas as respostas estão vindo com <br /> no fim.

Comment: Queria colocar o código que estou fazendo aqui, mas não sei onde coloco.

Comment: Esse detalhe eu não sabia. Vou reavaliar aqui...

Comment: Tem um link para editar a pergunta. Coloque o código lá.

Comment: sim. Fiz o seguinte agora, tirei o "<" que você disse e dei um replace em asp mesmo nos campos para limpar os <br>

Comment: agora vou ver se consigo fazer o seguinte: a questão vem toda desarrumada quando pego do pdf e colo no fckeditor, gostaria de colocar ela arrumadinha para que o REGEX consiga fazer o que quero para inserir no banco certinho. Pois precisa tá no padrão.

Comment: será que isso consigo com um evento load em jquery?

Comment: Tenta esse regex: `((.*?)\n){1}`

Comment: Foi não, a pergunta preencheu as respostas. Cada um pedaço entrou em uma resposta diferente.

Comment: Quando vc cola no Editor, fica assim, exatamente desta forma como mostra esta imagem? https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Ynp.jpg

Comment: Não. fica exatamente assim https://regexr.com/3q2ad tá vendo os espaços antes das letras?

Comment: pra casar com o meu regex tenho que tirar esses espaços antes, posso fazer isso na mão, mas se automatizasse era melhor.

Comment: Consegui fazer sem regex, dá uma testada [neste link](http://ticianawerner.com.br/teste1/teste.asp).