# preg_match retornando 0

Tags: php, regex

Boa tarde,
Eu tenho uma string que recebo do banco de dados

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head> <body> <div> </div> <div> </div> <div> <h3> </h3> <p> </p> <p> </p> <p> </p> <p> </p> <p> </p> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <h6> </h6> <br /><br /><br /><br /> <p>Portaria n&ordm; 69 de 18/01/2017 - Publicada no DOU de 19/01/2017</p> <br /> <h3>Certificamos que</h3> <h5>{NOME_ALUNO}</h5> <h3>concluiu em {DT_APR} o <br />{NOME_CURSO}<br />realizado pela ---- na qualidade de aluno(a), perfazendo um total de {CARGA_HOR} horas.</h3> <h3><em> </em></h3> <h4><em>Cidade </em>{DATE_EXT}<em> .</em></h4> </div> </body> </html>
```

e estou tentando fazer um regex nesta string `preg_match('/^<!\w+\s\w+>\s<\w+>\s<\w+>\s<\/\w+>/', $texto);`

porém ele sempre retorna 0, e se eu testo a regex em sites como https://regexr.com/ ele me retorna o resultado esperado.

Alguém pode apontar meu erro?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você recebe esse HTML de um retorno do banco?

Comment: Sim, preciso arrancar esse cabeçalho porque esta gerando erro em outro processo, porém fiquei barrado na regex, e tentar tirar com str_replace também não funciona.

Comment: O correto é `preg_match('/^<!\w+\s\w+>\s<\w+>\s<\w+>\s<\/\w+>/', $texto, $output); var_dump($output);`. Está retornando "0" pois, provavelmente, não está capturando o resultado.

Comment: Fazer parse de html com regex é simplesmente errado, e é normal que não resolva todos os casos que quer. Pergunta relacionada [Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129557/por-que-regex-n%C3%A3o-deve-ser-utilizado-para-tratar-html)

Comment: Na minha humilde opinião, o correto **mesmo** é usar um parser de HTML (a menos que você tenha certeza absoluta que as strings sempre começam exatamente com `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head>`). Mas se tiver qualquer coisa dentro do `head`, por exemplo, a regex já não funciona. Se não tiver exatamente 1 espaço entre as tags, se tiver algum comentário, se tiver atributos (`<html lang="en">`), etc etc.. Eu entendo a "tentação" de usar regex, parece tão fácil e rápido (e muitas vezes é mesmo), mas para parsing de HTML, é melhor usar parsers específicos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: Provavelmente ele não está fazendo parsing, está apenas tratando uma string como string, tendo ou não código HTML. Isso é uma string: `"eu sou uma string"`, e isso também é uma string: `"<b>eu sou uma string</b>"`... agora, fazer parsing é outra história.

Comment: @hkotsubo hehe, eu mesmo ia colocar esse mitico link mas depois acabei não o fazendo! Mas alguem salvou o dia :D. Boa leitura para qualquer pessoa!

Comment: @sam Como eu disse, se existe a "certeza absoluta" que as strings sempre estarão nesse formato, a regex serve. Mas se pode vir qualquer HTML (com as variações que mencionei) aí é melhor usar um parser, pois a regex pode acabar ficando complicada demais. A maioria dos parsers dá a opção de manipular o DOM (que no fim é o que ele quer fazer, remover algumas tags). Não sou contra regex, sou contra usar a ferramenta menos adequada para cada caso :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo O problema é que ele quer remover `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head>`, correto?! Como se remove a abertura da tag `<html>` sem remover o elemento todo usando manipuladores DOM? Ser tiver como aí concordo em usar manipuladores.

Comment: @sam Mas aí que tá: se o início sempre é `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head>`, não é mais fácil usar substr? E se o início é variável, talvez seja melhor usar um parser (a menos que as variações sejam simples, mas sem mais exemplos, não tenho como avaliar o que é melhor). Na verdade eu voltaria um passo atrás e veria porque é necessário um html que não tem a tag `html` no início (esse parece ser o verdadeiro problema) :-)

Comment: Então, o que ocorre é o seguinte, existe a geração de um pdf usando mpdf, ele tem 2 páginas, mas por algum motivo estava aparecendo apenas a primeira página. Depois de muito procurar eu vi que o problema é nessa tag html, ele ta criando todo um html dentro de outro, como teste eu tirei o campo que informei acima e coloquei na mão mesmo a string que sobrou, ai deu certo, e é por isso que preciso arrancar essas tags. Não faço ideia do motivo de terem salvado assim no banco mas agora sobrou pra eu resolver essa bronca.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @sam sim, consegui usando a função strip_tags. Obrigado.

Comment: Mas porque não pode ter o `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head>` se é um conteúdo html ? Isso parece me muito estranho tal como o @hkotsubo já mencionou e só seguindo esse caminho você consegue realmente resolver corretamente. A solução que tem a mim parece um remendo, que talvez precise de mais remendos no futuro.

Comment: @sam Apenas para complementar, há um problema quando a regex **não** der *match* na string. Veja [**aqui**](https://regex101.com/r/Ylnqox/1/debugger) que a regex tem que fazer backtracking (ir e voltar várias vezes porque não achou um *match*). Para um único caso pode até nem "fazer cócegas" no desempenho, mas se você tiver que processar muitos arquivos, por exemplo, já pode começar a fazer diferença. Enfim, não quer dizer que para um único arquivo a regex não sirva, mas é importante saber as implicações de usar cada abordagem: https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: @Isac existia uma página html, contendo cabeçalho, tags de estilos divs e tudo mais, e em uma dessas divs era inserido a string que informei acima. Tudo isso num arquivo php que gera um PDF que pode ou não ter mais de 1 página. Quando era só uma página, maravilha, funcionava normal, quando tinha mais por algum motivo que eu realmente não sei ele não criava a segunda página por nada no mundo, depois de muito testar vi que era por causa desse cabeçalho html que estava vindo na string. Tirei o cabeçalho e ele funcionou normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicando o preg_match:

A função preg_match() aceita 5 parâmetros, sendo os dois primeiros obrigatórios.

- O primeiro parâmetro é a expressão regular ($pattern).
- O segundo parâmetro é a string onde pesquisaremos a expressão ($subject).
- O terceiro parâmetro é um array que armazenará o termo que casou ($matches).

fiz um teste com o seu código e veja o que deu:

```
$texto = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head> <body> <div> </div> <div> </div> <div> <h3> </h3> <p> </p> <p> </p> <p> </p> <p> </p> <p> </p> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <h6> </h6> <br /><br /><br /><br /> <p>Portaria nº 69 de 18/01/2017 - Publicada no DOU de 19/01/2017</p> <br /> <h3>Certificamos que</h3> <h5>{NOME_ALUNO}</h5> <h3>concluiu em {DT_APR} o <br />{NOME_CURSO}<br />realizado pela ---- na qualidade de aluno(a), perfazendo um total de {CARGA_HOR} horas.</h3> <h3><em> </em></h3> <h4><em>Cidade </em>{DATE_EXT}<em> .</em></h4> </div> </body> </html>";

$matches = array();

$resultado = preg_match('/^<!\w+\s\w+>\s<\w+>\s<\w+>\s<\/\w+>/', $texto, $matches);

var_dump($resultado, $matches);
```

Dando um var_dump veja o resultado:

```
int(1) array(1) { [0]=> string(37) " " }
```

Explicando o que você está tentando com seu REGEX:

`^` Indica que é a posição inicial da string

`<!` encontra todos os caracteres literais `<!` (case sensitive)

`\w+` Encontra qualquer caracter (que contenha o seguinte padrão [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`+` Quantificador — Encontra uma ou mais vezes, quantas vezes forem possíveis, voltando 
atrás se necessário (greedy)

`\s` Encontra qualquer espaço em branco (pode ser [\r\n\t\f\v ])

`\w+` Encontra qualquer caracter (que contenha o seguinte padrão [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`+` Quantificador — Encontra uma ou mais vezes, quantas vezes forem possíveis, voltando 
atrás se necessário (greedy)

`>` Encontra o caracter > (case sensitive)

`\s` busca por espaços vazios (pode ser [\r\n\t\f\v ])

`<` Encontra o caracter < (case sensitive)

`\w+` Encontra qualquer caracter (que contenha o seguinte padrão [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`+` Quantificador — Encontra uma ou mais vezes, quantas vezes forem possíveis, voltando 
atrás se necessário (greedy)

`>` Encontra o caracter > (case sensitive)

`\s` busca por espaços vazios (pode ser [\r\n\t\f\v ])

`<` Encontra o caracter < (case sensitive)

`\w+` Encontra qualquer caracter (que contenha o seguinte padrão [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`>` Encontra o caracter > (case sensitive)

`\s` busca por espaços vazios (pode ser [\r\n\t\f\v ])

`<` Encontra o caracter < (case sensitive)

`\/` Encontra o caracter / (case sensitive)

`\w+` Encontra qualquer caracter (que contenha o seguinte padrão [a-zA-Z0-9_])

`>` Encontra o caracter > (case sensitive)

ao juntar tudo isso temos o seu regex `/^<!\w+\s\w+>\s<\w+>\s<\w+>\s<\/\w+>/`

Se o que você está querendo é remover as tags HTML de uma string basta usar a função strip_tags():

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

strip_tags — Retira as tags HTML e PHP de uma string

strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

> Parâmetros

**str**
A string de entrada.

**allowable_tags**
Você pode utilizar o segundo parâmetro, que é opcional, para indicar tags que não devam ser retiradas.

> Nota:

Comentários HTML e tags PHP também são retirados. E isto não pode ser modificado com allowable_tags.

Exemplo strip_tags()

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

Referencia: [PHP: strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Vou tentar fazer dessa forma. Obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou com strip_tags. Muito Obrigado!!