# preg_match_all não retorna todos valores

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Preciso obter os títulos das páginas de um txt mas não consigo obter os valores corretos de saída com `preg_match_all`, sempre me retorna apenas o resultado da última linha de IP do arquivo.txt.

Meu código:

```
<?php  

$arquivo = fopen ("arquivo.txt", "r"); 
$num_linhas = 0; 

while (!feof ($arquivo)) {
    $linha=fgets($arquivo);
    if ($linha != "\n" && $linha != "") {
        $num_linhas++; $ultima = $linha;
    }
} 

fclose ($arquivo); 
$linhas = explode("\n", file_get_contents('arquivo.txt',null,null));
$ch = curl_init();
foreach ($linhas as $url) {
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_exec($ch);
    $file_contents = ob_get_contents();
    $resultado = preg_match_all('#<title>([^<\/]{1,})<\/title>#i', $file_contents, $matches);
}
ob_end_clean();
curl_close($ch);

print_r($matches);
```

Quando executo `print_r ($matches);` em uma lista com apenas dois IP's me retorna o último valor apenas. Como abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <TITLE>Page Not Found</TITLE>
        )

)
```

Conteúdo do arquivo.txt

```
151.101.1.69
151.80.204.60
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece por causa dos parênteses neste trecho da regex: `([^<\/]{1,})`.

Os parênteses formam um [grupo de captura](https://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e segundo a documentação de [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), no array de *matches* os grupos são colocados separadamente:

> *Orders results so that `$matches[0]` is an array of full pattern matches, `$matches[1]` is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.*

Ou seja, em `$matches[0]` eu tenho um array com todo o trecho capturado pela regex, em `$matches[1]` tenho o conteúdo capturado pelo primeiro grupo de captura, etc (os grupos são numerados conforme a ordem em que aparecem na regex, como a sua só tem um par de parênteses, então só terá um grupo de captura).

Então você pode ignorar `$matches[1]`, ou então remover o grupo de captura da sua regex:

```
$file_contents = '<title>Fastly error: unknown domain 151.101.1.69</title>';
if (preg_match_all('#<title>[^<\/]+<\/title>#i', $file_contents, $matches)) {
    print_r ($matches);
}
```

Removi os parênteses, e também troquei o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{1,}` por `+`, que são equivalentes (ambos correspondem a "uma ou mais ocorrências"). A saída é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <title>Fastly error: unknown domain 151.101.1.69</title>
        )

)
```

---

Mas na verdade, se está manipulando HTML, é melhor usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument):

```
$file_contents = '<title>Fastly error: unknown domain 151.101.1.69</title>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($file_contents);
$list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
if ($list->length > 0) {
    $title = $list->item(0);
    // imprimir a tag
    print_r($dom->saveHTML($title)); // <title>Fastly error: unknown domain 151.101.1.69</title>

    // pegar somente o conteúdo da tag
    echo $list->item(0)->textContent; // Fastly error: unknown domain 151.101.1.69
}
```

Isso porque [regex não é a melhor ferramenta para manipular HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052) (para casos mais simples pode até "funcionar", mas também [podem acontecer coisas terríveis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)). Enfim, use a ferramenta mais adequada para cada caso, [regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

---

Além disso, você está chamando `preg_match_all` dentro de um *loop* `foreach`, mas está imprimindo o resultado fora do *loop*. Desse jeito ele só vai imprimir o último resultado. Se quer imprimir o resultado de todas as chamadas, coloque o `print_r` dentro do *loop*:

```
foreach ( $linhas as $url ) {
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_exec($ch);
    $file_contents = ob_get_contents();
    if (preg_match_all('#<title>[^<\/]+<\/title>#i', $file_contents, $matches)) {
        print_r ($matches);
    }
}
```

Repare também no `if` para verificar se `preg_match_all` encontrou algo (se não encontrar, ele não entra no `if`, pois aí não haverá o que imprimir).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.Em relação ao Regex, realmente tinha um erro, mas continua a imprimir apenas o título do último valor do arquivo.txt.Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @AntônioFagundes Por favor [edite a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/438374/edit) e coloque o conteúdo do arquivo. Se ele for muito grande, reduza-o, mas de forma que o erro se mantenha.

Comment: Editado como pedido.

Comment: @AntônioFagundes Bom, acho que o problema é que o `print_r` está fora do `foreach`. Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Dessa forma ele não reconhece nenhuma entrada,não entra no if pelo que me parece.Como isso é possível?

Comment: @AntônioFagundes Não sei, não consigo reproduzir o mesmo erro aqui. Talvez seja algum outro detalhe, sei lá. Tentou chamar diretamente com valores fixos em vez de ler do arquivo?

Comment: Acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: @AntônioFagundes Talvez o `curl` não esteja retornando todo o arquivo (é um palpite, pq não dá pra eu saber o que tem em cada IP - pois se tiver um `title`, a regex retorna, então se não entra no `if` é porque não tem `title` no texto)

Comment: Eu postei o endereço dos ip na pergunta, ao final da mesma.Tem a tag title nos dois, mas me retorna em branco.Estou pensando que é o firewall da minha rede.Engraçado que pelo browser consigo acessar.

Comment: @AntônioFagundes Então deve ser esse o problema (algo relacionado à rede)