# Como obter o conteúdo de um elemento HTML a partir de uma String com Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou criando uma aplicação que lê o conteúdo de uma página na internet e depois obtém o texto de um elemento `<textarea>` desse conteúdo. Para realizar tal tarefa, eu decidi utilizar *regex*.

O problema é que não tenho muito conhecimento em *regex* e não consigo desenvolver uma lógica em JavaScript para obter o texto do elemento. Abaixo está uma String de exemplo e o código que tentei fazer para obter o texto:

```
content = '4354543/sfd f^^ <textarea id="text">Hello World! 34% #_2@.;/°? </textarea> fr fdgdf //fdg3';

result = content.match(/<textarea id="text">\w*/)[0];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Entendi que vc decidiu usar a RegEx. Mas não seria melhor usar o método `getElementById()`, já que sua string é uma página HTML?

Comment: E como eu usaria esse método com uma string ?

Comment: Vou elaborar uma resposta com os 2 métodos.

Comment: Ah tem mais uma coisa, eu vou utilizar isso para uma aplicação rodando em Node. Mas ainda sim, deixe a resposta com o método `getElementById` se possível, pois fiquei curioso sobre isso.

Comment: Tudo bem. Só vou usar javascript.

Comment: Mais facil `<textarea[^>]*>([^<]*)` provavelmente (se tiver que apelar tanto assim, a ponto de precisar de RegEx, claro)

Comment: Acho importante adicionar a tag `node` a pergunta, já que no Node não tem a API nativa para manipulação do DOM, o que muda bastante as possíveis respostas

Comment: DOMParser ou qq outra API é bem mais garantido, pois basta o HTML mudar um pouco pra quebrar a regex. Por ex, se o textarea estiver dentro de comentários (`<!-- <textarea> etc -->`), a regex não detecta (e uma regex pra reconhecer comentários HTML é bem complicada), já DOMParser ignora corretamente (é só um exemplo, há vários outros casos que fazem regex ser inviável dependendo do caso) - por fim, vale sempre ler [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: @Costamilam o problema é se invalidar alguma das respostas. Nem sei o que é melhor nesse caso.

Comment: @Bacco seria melhor já ter sido criada com a tag, mas enfim, ainda acho útil manter as outras respostas, já que não tem o porque de criar um nova pergunta para quando se quiser o mesmo, porém no navegador

Comment: Opa! Você já ouviu falar no [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)? Você pode carregar seu HTML nele e persistir com consultas para conseguir extrair os dados que você quer. A documentação é bem simples e provavelmente você terá um resulado bem bacana.

Comment: Só pra complementar (e fazer um pequeno "jabá"), [acabei de responder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) justamente sobre isso (usar um parser versus regex), inclusive mostrando alguns exemplos para ilustrar melhor porque a solução com regex é pior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a bilioteca [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) para obter acesso a uma API de manipulação do DOM, porém não sei dizer se é a nativa ou apenas simula a nativa:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM("<!DOCTYPE html><textarea>Hello world</textarea>");

console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("textarea").value);
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava.

Comment: Esqueça o que eu comentei, agora entendi que a questão é sobre Node.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a API do DOMParser não existe no Node, ou não? Você pode criar sua resposta com a melhor solução que imagina. Eu preferia usar a lib junto com o `fetch` se ela facilitar e não houver algo que impeça

Comment: @Costamilam foi o que eu disse, a pergunta do autor é ambigua, tive que ler os comentarios para ver que se tratava de Node, no caso a saída parece ser mesmo usar pacotes como respondeu.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DOMParser` desta forma:

```js
var content = '4354543/sfd f^^ <textarea id="text">Hello World! 34% #_2@.;/°? </textarea> fr fdgdf //fdg3';
var result = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/html");
document.write(result.querySelector("#text").textContent);

// ou result.getElementById("text").textContent
```

Ele converte a string num objeto `document` com os nós. Aí basta buscar o `id` desejado com `.querySelector` ou `.getElementById`.

Comment: Vale dizer que se ele for pegar o conteúdo com ajax, nem do DOMParser precisa (o ajax ja pode receber um Document)

Comment: Obrigado Sam! Estou desenvolvendo a aplicação em Node mas também queria saber sobre  utilizar o `querySelector` com uma string. Tenho certeza que vou utilizar o `DOMParser` bastante no futuro :)

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Blz. Mas acho que não precisa carregar um biblioteca externa pra fazer algo tão simples.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a ideia de parsear com expressão regular, poderia ser assim:

```js
var str = '4354543/sfd f^^ <textarea id="text">Hello World! 34% #_2@.;/°? </textarea> fr fdgdf //fdg3';
matchs = str.match(/\<textarea[\s\S]*?id\=\"text\"[\s\S]*?\>([\s\S]+?)\<\/textarea\>/);
console.log(matchs[1]);
```

Em resumo, eu busco a abertura da tag `textarea` que tenha o `id="text"`, seguido de um grupo de busca, que será o índice `1` do match, seguido do fechamento da tag `textarea`.

A classe de caracteres `[\s\S]` é um "macete" que encontra qualquer coisa MESMO. Pulo do gato muito explanado pelo @hkotsubo. Isso não vai quebrar a busca caso tenha quebra de linha e etc.

Não vou abordar tudo que foi usado na expressão regular, já que é aceitável uma solução melhor que vou apresentar:

```js
var str = (
    '<textarea id="um_id_qualquer">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</textarea>'
    +'<textarea id="2_id_qualquer">Dignissimos ducimus quas illo a expedita pariatur maxime magni,</textarea>'
    +'<textarea id="tres_id_qualquer">amet sint laborum eveniet, quam,</textarea>'
    +'<textarea id="text">Hello World! 34% #_2@.;/°? </textarea>'
    +'<textarea id="4_id_qualquer">recusandae enim iste delectus quidem! Iusto, at amet!</textarea>'
);

var parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");

console.log(parser.getElementById('text').innerHTML);
```

Como a `str` é um HTML válido, basta criar um `DOMParser` e usar os métodos do próprio DOM.

Comment: Obrigado Lip por me ajudar.

Comment: `([\s\S]+)` vai dar problema se tiver 2 textarea. ou usa +? pra não ficar "fominha", ou faz como eu fiz no comment da pergunta `[^<]*` "tudo menos <"

Comment: @Bacco pior que eu coloquei o "anti-fominha" em todas as classes e esqueci dessa. Vlw por notificar! kk PS: Prefiro bindar o fechamento da tag por completo. Vai que o conteúdo do `textarea` tenha um simples "menor que" (`<`)...