# Regex não pega todos os textos das tags span

Tags: html, python, regex, beautifulsoup

Sei que existem parsers de HTML, mas como o meu HTML não está bem estruturado, preciso usar também expressões regulares.

O HTML é assim:

```
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<td colspan="2"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">1º 

                          Período Ideal</span></font></td>
<td><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">Créd.<br/>

                          Aula</span></font></td>
<td><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">Créd.<br/>

                          Trab.</span></font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">CH</span></font></td>
<td align="center" width="6%"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">CE</span></font></td>
<td align="center" width="6%"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">CP</span></font></td>
<td align="center" width="6%"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">ATPA</span></font></td>
</tr>
```

E a regex é:

```
r'''<span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">(.*?)</span>'''
```

Estou tentando pegar o texto `'1º Período Ideal'`, mas a regex não o reconhece, embora outros trechos sejam reconhecidos, como `'CE'`, `'CP'` e `'ATPA'`, e eu não entendo o motivo.

Answer (score 8):

## Não use regex para *parsing* de HTML

Já que a pergunta tem a *tag* [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup), por que não usar [essa biblioteca](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), que é feita justamente para fazer *parsing* e manipulação de HTML, em vez de regex?

Se o HTML está mal formado/estruturado, você pode instalar *parsers* alternativos, [citados na própria documentação do Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-a-parser). No seu caso, acredito que a opção seria usar o *html5lib*, que é o mais permissivo dos *parsers* (a documentação diz que, apesar de ser mais lento, ele é tão permissivo quanto os *browsers*, que [são conhecidos por aceitarem HTML's extremamente mal formados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup)). Não ficou claro o quão mal formado está seu HTML, mas acho que vale o teste.

De qualquer forma, [regex não foi feito para trabalhar com HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052) (pode até "funcionar" em muitos casos, mas como você mesmo já começou a perceber, [não é a ferramenta mais adequada para a tarefa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)).

Com Beautiful Soup, ficaria assim:

```py
html = '''
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<td colspan="2"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">1º 

                          Período Ideal</span></font></td>
<td><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">Créd.<br/>

                          Aula</span></font></td>
<td><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">Créd.<br/>

                          Trab.</span></font></td>
<td align="center"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">CH</span></font></td>
<td align="center" width="6%"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">CE</span></font></td>
<td align="center" width="6%"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">CP</span></font></td>
<td align="center" width="6%"><font color="#000000" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1"><span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">ATPA</span></font></td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for span in soup.find_all('span', class_='txt_arial_8pt_black'):
    print(span.text)
```

O código acima busca todos os `span`'s que tem a classe "txt_arial_8pt_black", e imprime o respectivo texto de cada uma. Detalhe que as quebras de linha presentes no HTML também serão impressas:

```
1º 

                          Período Ideal
Créd.

                          Aula
Créd.

                          Trab.
CH
CE
CP
ATPA
```

Se quiser usar o outro *parser* já citado, que lida melhor com HTML mal formado, basta mudar para:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

Não esquecendo, claro, de instalá-lo, [conforme consta na documentação](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-a-parser).

---

#### Mas se quiser muito mesmo usar regex...

<sup>*Abaixo eu mostro algumas soluções com regex, e você entenderá porque usar o Beautiful Soup é uma solução muito melhor.*</sup>

A sua regex não funciona em todos os casos porque o ponto corresponde a [qualquer caractere, **exceto quebras de linha**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). E como algumas tags `span` tem quebras de linha no texto, `.*` não vai pegar esses trechos - como é o caso da tag que você mencionou:

```html
<span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">1º 

                          Período Ideal</span>
```

Uma alternativa é usar a [*flag* `DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), que faz com que o ponto também corresponda a quebras de linha:

```py
import re
for texto in re.findall(r'<span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">(.*?)</span>', html, re.DOTALL):
    print(texto)
```

Usei `findall` para buscar todas as ocorrências existentes no HTML. O detalhe é que o trecho que corresponde ao conteúdo da tag está entre parênteses e isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) diz que `findall` retorna somente os grupos quando estes estão presentes, por isso a variável `texto` já tem o texto da tag a cada iteração.

Isso "funciona", mas com muitas limitações (e nem me refiro ao fato da regex retornar também as tags `<br/>` junto do texto, que não ficou claro se é para retornar ou não). Se o HTML mudar um pouco, já vai exigir modificações na regex, que não seriam necessárias se usássemos o Beautiful Soup.

Por exemplo, se a tag tiver outros atributos ou simplesmente outra classe, como `<span id="abc" class="txt_arial_8pt_black">` ou `<span class="outra_classe txt_arial_8pt_black">`. Pronto, já quebrou a regex (mas o primeiro código com Beautiful Soup continuará achando essas tags sem problemas). Uma alternativa seria:

```py
r'<span[^>]+class="[^"]*\btxt_arial_8pt_black\b[^"]*"[^>]*>(.*?)</span>'
```

Ou seja, a regex considera que pode ter `[^>]+` (um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `>`) antes do `class`, e dentro do `class` pode ter zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam aspas (`[^"]*`) antes e depois de "txt_arial_8pt_black" (e o [atalho `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) é para garantir que não haverá classes como "txt_arial_8pt_black2", por exemplo).

Mas e se tiver um `span` dentro de outro (o que é [perfeitamente possível](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9089953))?

```html
<span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">Antes <span>Durante</span> Depois</span>
```

O Beautiful Soup pega corretamente todo o texto `"Antes Durante Depois"`, mas a regex só pega `Antes <span>Durante` (obs: se quiser que o Beautiful Soup retorne todo o conteúdo do `span`, incluindo as tags, troque `span.text` por `span.decode_contents()`). Isso acontece porque a regex usa *lazy quantifier* (o `?` logo depois do `.*` - veja mais informações [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052)), ou seja, ele pega a menor quantidade possível de caracteres que satisfaça a expressão. Isso faz a regex parar no primeiro `</span>` que encontrar ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/KEOr1j/1/)).

E se eu retirar o *lazy quantifier*, aí ela se torna [gananciosa](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e pega a maior quantidade possível de caracteres, ou seja, ela pega tudo até o último `</span>` ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/KEOr1j/2/)).

Nesse caso, até daria para usar algo como:

```py
r'<span[^>]+class="[^"]*\btxt_arial_8pt_black\b[^"]*"[^>]*>(.*?)</span>(?![^<>]*</span>)'
```

O [*lookeahead* negativo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?![^<>]*</span>)` verifica se depois do fechamento da tag não há outro fechamento, mas agora a regex falha se no meio tiver alguma outra tag que não seja `span`, ex:

```html
<span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">Antes <span>Durante</span><br> Depois</span>
```

O `<br>` entre os dois `</span>` já quebra a regex, e aí você tem que mudá-la novamente para que considere este caso. Uma alternativa seria:

```py
r'<span[^>]+class="[^"]*\btxt_arial_8pt_black\b[^"]*"[^>]*>(.*?)</span>(?!(?:</?(?!\bspan\b)[^<>]*>|[^<>])*</span>)'
```

Agora o *lookahead* negativo `(?!(?:</?(?!\bspan\b)[^<>]*>|[^<>])` verifica se tem algum caractere que não é `<` nem `>`, ou uma tag que não é `span` (usando outro *lookahead* só para isso, ou seja, um *lookahead* dentro de outro - que para mim já é um dos sinais de que a coisa está mais complexa do que deveria).

Apesar de funcionar para o caso citado, será que vale a pena usar essa regex? Pense na manutenção futura disso, e compare com o código do Beautiful Soup lá em cima. Além disso, a regex retorna sempre o conteúdo do `span` com as tags, enquanto o Beautiful Soup dá a opção de retornar somente o texto sem as tags. Para eliminar as tags usando regex, você precisaria de [outra só para isso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11229831).

---

Perceba que para cada caso diferente a mais, surge uma nova complicação na regex, e a expressão vai ficando cada vez maior, mais complexa e difícil de entender e manter. Já o código com Beautiful Soup seria o mesmo citado no início, então será que vale a pena insistir em usar regex?

Tem ainda outros casos, como por exemplo se a tag estiver dentro de comentários:

```html
<!--
comentários HTML, etc
<a href="blabla">estou comentado</a>
<span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">também estou comentado</span>
<p>comentado, me ignorem</p>
-->
<span class="txt_arial_8pt_black">não estou comentado</span>
```

O Beautiful Soup ignora o primeiro `span`, pois ele está comentado, enquanto a regex não, pois ela não consegue avaliar o que está "em volta" da tag, e por isso não detecta que ela está dentro de um comentário. Até é possível mudar a regex para detectar esses casos, mas será que vale a pena adicionar [algo assim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42097865) em uma expressão que por si só já está bem complexa, sendo que com Beautiful Soup o código seria o mesmo que está no início da resposta?

E só estamos considerando os casos em que existe o fechamento da tag. Mas como você disse que o HTML está mal formado, então teremos que considerar que nem sempre a tag terá o respectivo fechamento? Nesse caso será pior ainda ter uma regex que contemple todas as situações possíveis: talvez tenha que deixar os fechamentos opcionais (mas como saber que a tag terminou?), detectar algumas variações de tags mal formadas - e a complexidade vai depender de como estão estas tags - etc. Enfim, dependendo de como está o HTML, fazer uma ou mais expressões será trabalhoso demais e na minha opinião não valerá a pena.

Não me entenda mal, [regex são legais](https://xkcd.com/208/) - eu gosto bastante - e muitas vezes *parece* ser a melhor solução. [Mas nem sempre é](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) (para manipular HTML, [com certeza não é](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)).

Answer (score 3):

o problema específico desta tag, no exemplo que está aí, é que o conteúdo da célula se estende por mais de uma linha. Você nao colocou seu código Python (é dificil responder a pergunta assim), mas você tem que adicionar a flag  `re.DOTALL` à chamada que executa a expressão regular.  (não tem como dar exemplo, já que não sabemos qual função você está usando). Essa flag indica para o engine que todo o bloco de texto deve ser tratado em conjunto, e não que cada nova linha "inicia novamente" um bloco de texto onde aplicar a expressão regular.

Acho que em todas as chamadas do módulo `re`, as flags são o último parâmetro  - é só adicionar o `re.DOTALL` na sua chamada.

**Perceba** que mesmo funcionando, expressões regulares não são a forma masi adequada de se extrair conteúdo web - você pode usar se quer algo bem específico, em páginas que você sabe como estão - e que não parseiam direito, como é esse caso - mas uma expressão regular "universal" que dê conta de qualquer estrutura válida no HTML não só seria muito difícil de escrever e manter, como seria algo monstruoso -seria muito mais fácil fazer um parser. Não enfatizo mais esse ponto, por que esse HTML aí realmente é bem ruim - então, ua solução ad-hoc pode ser o melhor a fazer.

**No entanto** você está fazendo um uso bastante ineficiente de expressões regulares aí: voce está passando caracteres exatos, sem usar nenhum dos recursos para garantir que você continue pegando seus resultados se mudar o nome da classe no elemento `spam`, ou se tiver um espaço a mais em algum lugar, ou outras tags, etc...  - pode ser que funcione assim sempre, e pode ser que quebre derrepente, ou que você deixe de pegar tags que nem perceba que estão lá por conta de espaçamento, etc... O ideal seria usar uma regexp mais flexível do que essa aí.

Comment: Na verdade a flag a ser usada é `DOTALL`, pois a `MULTILINE` só muda o comportamento do `^` e `$` (eles passam a considerar também o início e fim de cada linha). Já o `DOTALL` faz com que o ponto corresponda a quebras de linha, e aí sim "funciona": https://ideone.com/HbKC2C - pessoalmente eu acho confuso o nome `MULTILINE`, e pra piorar algumas engines chamam o DOTALL de "single line", o que deixa tudo mais confuso ainda. Mas de qq forma, acho que regex nem é a melhor solução, conforme eu falo na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) :-)

Comment: Troquei para o .DOTALL - mas vou manter a resposta, já que deve reolver o problema do A.P. agora - vou enfatizar que não se deve usar regexps, no entanto.