# Print elementos de um regex em sequência no python

Tags: python, regex

Boa tarde pessoal, sou novo no python e estou aprendendo ao poucos com isso gostaria de pedir ajuda de vocês, eu tenho o seguinte código fonte retirado de um site:

```
<div class='numerando'>1 - 1</div><div class='episodiotitle'><a href='https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x1-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/'>Extreme Aggressor</a> <span class='date'>Sep. 22, 2005</span></div></li><li class='mark-2'><div class='imagen'><img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/d46a4eVjnECDSzKGJDNCSRQGrRo.jpg'></div><div class='numerando'>1 - 2</div><div class='episodiotitle'><a href='https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x2-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/'>Compulsion</a> <span class='date'>Sep. 28, 2005</span></div></li>
```

Com isso fiz esse pequeno código com o seguinte regex:

```
site = "https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/series/mente-criminosa-dublado-hd/"
response = requests.get(site)
data = response.content
data.decode('utf-8')

match = re.findall(b'<div class=\'numerando\'>(.*?)</div><div class=\'episodiotitle\'><a href=\'(.*?)\'>(.*?)</a>', data)
```

Já tentei de várias formas imprimir da seguinte forma o código:

Episódio 1 - 1 Extreme Aggressor | Link : https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x1-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/

Episódio 1 - 2 Compulsion | Link : https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x2-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/

```
onde 1 - 1 vem de <div class='numerando'>1 - 1</div>

E nome do episódio e link vem de <div class='episodiotitle'><a href='https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x1-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/'>Extreme Aggressor</a>
```

Dando um print(match) ele mostra corretamente todos os dados que eu quero pegar, porém eu não consigo filtra-los da forma que citei acima

Tentei com vários códigos que encontrei em tutoriais na internet e alguns tópicos aqui do próprio stack, mas não consegui com nenhum, tentei também entender o beautifulsoup mas não tive muito sucesso, na verdade eu não sei qual é a melhor forma de se fazer isso no python, agradeço desde já a ajuda de vocês!

Comment: Não use regex para trabalhar com HTML: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052 <-- esse link mostra como a regex pode se tornar cada vez mais complicada, enquanto se usar a ferramenta certa, como por exemplo o beautiful soup, é bem melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certamente a `BeautifulSoup` é a biblioteca mais adequada para o seu caso, veja só:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/series/mente-criminosa-dublado-hd/'

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code != 200:
    print(f'Erro HTTP: {response.status_code}')
    sys.exit(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

episodios = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'episodios'})

for episodio in episodios.findAll('li'):
    div = episodio.find('div',{'class': 'numerando'})
    numeracao = div.text

    div = episodio.find('div',{'class': 'episodiotitle'})
    a = div.find('a', href=True)
    titulo, link = a.text, a['href']

    print(f'Episodio: {numeracao} {titulo} | Link: {link}')
```

Saída:

```
Episodio: 1 - 1 Extreme Aggressor | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x1-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 2 Compulsion | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x2-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 3 Won't Get Fooled Again | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x3-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 4 Plain Sight | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x4-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 5 Broken Mirror | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x5-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 6 L.S.D.K. | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x6-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 7 The Fox | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x7-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 8 Natural Born Killer | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/mentes-criminosas-1x8/
Episodio: 1 - 9 Derailed | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/mentes-criminosas-1x9/
Episodio: 1 - 10 The Popular Kids | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x10-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 11 Bloody Hungry | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x11-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 12 What Fresh Hell? | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/mentes-criminosas-1x12/
Episodio: 1 - 13 Poison | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x13-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 14 Riding the Lightning | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x14-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 15 Unfinished Business | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/mentes-criminosas-1x15/
Episodio: 1 - 16 The Tribe | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/mentes-criminosas-1x16/
Episodio: 1 - 17 A Real Rain | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x17-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 18 Somebody's Watching | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x18-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 19 Machismo | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x19-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 20 Charmed And Harm | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/mentes-criminosas-1x20/
Episodio: 1 - 21 Secrets And Lies | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/assistir-mentes-criminosas-1x21-dublado-e-legendado-online-hd/
Episodio: 1 - 22 The Fisher King (1) | Link: https://www.assistirseriesflix.com/episodios/mentes-criminosas-1x22/
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, estou entendendo pelo seu código o uso do Beautifulsoup nesse caso, não querendo pedir demais você conseguiria dar um exemplo usando o regex também por favor? Se não tiver problema claro, Obrigado