# Como fazer Backreferencing com Regex em PHP?

Tags: php, regex, php-7, preg-replace

Backreferencing para usar o mesmo texto novamente no pattern e deixar outro grupo na substituição apenas.

Pode ter ficado confuso, mas o que eu quero é assim.
A String é esta:

```
$Str = '
<p>Os <b>parágrafos</b> são as estruturas que compõe um texto e podem ser: longos, médios e curtos, 
dependendo do tipo de produção <a>textual</a>. Longos: estão mais presentes em textos científicos e acadêmicos, 
<i>os quais exigem uma</i> <strong>explicação</strong> mais complexa, com exemplos e especificações.</p>';
```

O objetivo é as tags strong, b, i e a serem substituídas apenas pelo conteúdo interno:

```
<b>Negrito</b>
```

Vira:

```
Negrito
```

Mas:

```
<b>Negrito</i>
```

Não pode ser mexido e permanece igual.
(Isso é provável de acontecer quando tem um negrito ou itálico dentro de um link ou vice-versa)

Tentei isto:

```
$Str = preg_replace(
    array(
        "/<(a|b|strong|i)>(.*?)<\/\1>/si"
    ),
    array(
        "$2"
    ),
    $Str
);
```

E isto:

```
$Str = preg_replace(
    array(
        "/<(a|b|strong|i)>(.*?)<\/$1>/si"
    ),
    array(
        "$2"
    ),
    $Str
);
```

Mas não parecem funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A princípio bastaria passar a regex e a string de substituição diretamente, sem usar array:

```
$Str = preg_replace('/<\b([abi]|strong)\b>(.*?)<\/\1>/', '$2', $Str);
```

Eu uso a [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[abi]` para determinar que pode ser qualquer uma dessas letras, ou `strong`, tudo cercado por `\b` (que é o atalho para ["fronteira entre palavras"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420506/112052), o que garante que não haverá outras letras antes ou depois do `a`, `b`, etc).

A [*backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` garante que a tag de fechamento é a mesma da tag de abertura, já que o nome da tag está entre parênteses, o que forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - e como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, então é o grupo 1 (por isso posso verificar se tem exatamente o mesmo conteúdo depois, usando `\1`).

---

Mas esta é uma abordagem bem "ingênua" e propensa a falhas. Em geral, [manipular HTML com regex não é o ideal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052) (veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) para alguns exemplos, e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) para a "resposta definitiva" sobre o assunto).

Por exemplo, se as tags tiverem atributos (como `<b id="whatever" class="algo">`) a regex já terá que ser adaptada, pois da forma que está, ela aceitaria apenas `<b>`. Se a tag estiver dentro de comentários (`<!-- <b>etc</b> -->`), a regex não detecta e vai substituir do mesmo jeito (e para que ela detecte comentários, teria que adicionar [algo desse tipo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42097865)). Enfim, para cada variação mínima do HTML, a regex vai ficando cada vez mais complicada e começa a não valer a pena.

O ideal é usar uma lib específica para HTML. No caso do PHP, você pode usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$Str = ... // string contendo o HTML

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($Str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//b | //strong | //i | //a') as $tag) { // procura b ou strong ou i ou a
    // troca a tag por um textNode contendo somente o texto
    $tag->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode($tag->textContent), $tag);
}
// imprimir o HTML final
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

---

Um detalhe é que se realmente tiver algo como `<b>Negrito</i>`, então **o HTML não é válido**. Se tiver tags aninhadas, o correto seria algo como `<b>Negrito <i>italic <a>link</a> etc</i> blabla</b>`, nunca teria uma abertura de `b` seguida do fechamento de `i` nem nada do tipo.

E `DOMDocument` aceita HTML inválido (vai dar alguns *warnings* e algumas tags serão "corrigidas" na medida do possível), mas aí você deveria tratar esse problema na origem - onde a string é gerada - para garantir que o HTML é válido, em vez de tentar consertar isso com regex, ou com qualquer outra ferramenta.

E para o caso de tags aninhadas (como um `a` dentro de `b` dentro de `i`, etc), a regex teria que usar [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) com recursão (ou seja, uma complicação desnecessária a mais):

```
function removeTags($input) {
    $regex = '/<\b([abi]|strong)\b>(.*?)<\/\1>/';

    if (is_array($input)) { // se é o resultado de um replace anterior
        $input = $input[2]; // pega o segundo grupo (conteúdo da tag)
    }

    return preg_replace_callback($regex, 'removeTags', $input);
}

$Str = removeTags($Str);
```

Já com `DOMDocument` não precisa disso, o código apresentado anteriormente já remove tags aninhadas.

Comment: Ajuda: comecei a usar DOMDocument recentemente e estou tendo dificuldade para detectar divs que tenham divs dentro delas como primeira child e eliminá-las - pode me ajudar?

Eu usei $excess_of_divs = $xpath->query("//div/div[0]"); para fazer a seleção mas não tô sabendo como eliminar somente a div que envolve alguma div como primeira child.

Comment: Aliás, eu deixei em array porque no meu código original eu tava fazendo diversas substituições.

Comment: @FelipeAlves A primeira div dentro de outra vc pega com `//div/div[1]` (e depois basta pegar o parentNode dela). Mas não querendo ser chato (e nem parecendo que não quero ajudar), a ideia do site é ter uma dúvida por problema específico. O problema da regex foi respondido acima, por favor diga se funcionou ou não (e **caso tenha funcionado**, considere marcá-la como correta - [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema)

Comment: Já o problema da div é diferente do que está na pergunta, e seria o caso de [fazer outra](/questions/ask) (não esquecendo de pesquisar antes, claro, pois já devem ter várias perguntas sobre xpath no site)

Comment: @FelipeAlves Ou, dependendo do que vc quer fazer, `//div/div[position()=1]` - enfim, um material legal sobre o assunto é esse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath