# Pegando o título de uma página HTML com sed ou awk

Tags: html, sed, awk

Tenho várias páginas HTML que gostaria de pegar o título, usando o `sed` ou o `awk`.

Quando faço com o `sed` ele retorna todo o conteúdo da página, e não somente o título.

Nas páginas o título vem assim:

```
<h1 style="color:#0F1A7F;margin:0px 10px 10px;border-bottom:1px solid #FF0000;font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'geneva', 'sans-serif', 'arial';"> Titulo da pagina </h1>
```

Usei este comando para pegar somente o 'Titulo da pagina':

```
k=$(sed 's/<[^>]*>//') pagina.html
```

Retorna todo o conteúdo da página.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` e `awk` (com expressões regulares - regex) não são as ferramentas mais adequadas para a tarefa. De maneira geral, [regex não foi feito para trabalhar com HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052) (pode até "funcionar" em muitos casos, mas [não é a ferramenta mais adequada para a tarefa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)).

Embora seja possível - e até "fácil" nos casos mais simples - é muito mais garantido usar um *parser* de HTML, e ao longo da resposta veremos os motivos.

Por exemplo, com `sed`, uma solução ingênua seria:

```bsh
sed -e 's/^.*<title>//' -e 's/<\/title>.*//' pagina.html
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu removo tudo desde o início até a *tag* `<title>`, e depois removo tudo de `</title>` em diante. O que sobrar é o título da página.

Mas no seu caso, como você quer pegar o conteúdo de um `h1`, então ficaria:

```bsh
sed -e 's/^.*<h1[^>]*>//' -e 's/<\/h1>.*//' pagina.html
```

Mas essa solução é simplista demais. Por exemplo, se o HTML tiver algo assim:

```html
    <title>título da página</title>
<!--     <title>title comentado</title> -->
```

O primeiro comando acima pegará a *tag* que está comentada. E alterar as regex para que detectem comentários [não é lá muito simples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42097865).

É por este e outros motivos que regex não é a melhor ferramenta para fazer *parsing* de HTML (veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052)).

---

Uma opção - melhor, na minha opinião - é usar o [`xmllint`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint), que é parte da [`libxml`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libxml) ([procure na Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=install+xmllint) como instalá-lo no seu sistema, não é difícil).

Com ele fica bem mais simples obter o `title` (e qualquer outra *tag*). Ex:

```bsh
xmllint --xpath '//title/text()' --html pagina.html
```

O comando acima devolve somente o texto da *tag* `title`. Se quiser também a *tag*, basta remover o `/text()`. Além disso, como ele é um *parser*, já consegue detectar - e ignorar - corretamente se a *tag* estiver dentro de comentários, como no exemplo acima.

No caso do `h1`, poderia ser algo como:

```bsh
xmllint --xpath '//h1[1]/text()' --html pagina.html
```

`h1[1]` serve para pegar apenas o primeiro `h1` (caso haja mais de um na página).