# preg_match_all pegar tag e atributos

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Link aparece assim:

```
< programme start="20210129023700 +0000" stop="20210129030100 +0000" channel="Foodnetworkhd.br">
< title lang="pt">Loucos por Churrasco - S3 E12 - Churrasco Tropical<\/title>
< desc lang="pt">Bobby Flay leva seu churrasco para as ilhas caribenhas com costela de porco grelhada, salada de radicchio e manga verde, além de batatas-doces grelhadas no estilo Hasselback e o coquetel Dark and Stormy. (n)</ desc>
</ programme>
```

Em PHP está assim:

```
{

//AQUI ESTA A QUESTÃO
  preg_match_all('/(start="(?<dt_con>.*?)".+stop="(?<ed_con>.*?)".+channel="(?<ch_name>.*?)".+\n)/i', $response, $channels, PREG_SET_ORDER);

}
```

Estou usando `foreach` para tratar os dados.

Comment: Já tentou usar `DomDocument` ou `SimpleXml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não use regex para ler XML/HTML/qualquer-outro-ML (veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) para mais detalhes, e no final tem uma breve explicação sobre isso).

Enfim, se está lidando com XML, uma opção melhor é usar uma lib dedicada, como por exemplo, [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Mas como o XML está mal-formado (pois na verdade são apenas "tags soltas", não há um elemento "root" englobando todas elas), a solução "feia" (mas que [o próprio Stack Overflow indica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4514559)) é lê-lo como HTML e usar `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` para ignorar os erros que dizem que ele está mal-formado.

```
$xml = <<<TEXTO
<programme start="20210129023700 +0000" stop="20210129030100 +0000" channel="Foodnetworkhd.br">
<title lang="pt">Loucos por Churrasco - S3 E12 - Churrasco Tropical<\/title>
<desc lang="pt">Bobby Flay leva seu churrasco para as ilhas caribenhas com costela de porco grelhada, salada de radicchio e manga verde, além de batatas-doces grelhadas no estilo Hasselback e o coquetel Dark and Stormy. (n)</desc>
</programme>
TEXTO;

// ler o XML
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHtml($xml);

// procurar pelas tags "programme"
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('programme') as $value) {
    // extrair os dados dela
    $nome = $value->nodeName; // nome da tag
    $start = $value->getAttribute('start'); // atributo start
    $stop = $value->getAttribute('stop'); // atributo stop
    $channel = $value->getAttribute('channel'); // atributo channel

    // usar os valores...
}
```

---

#### E por que regex não é uma boa ideia?

Para uma explicação mais detalhada, siga os links já citados no início. Mas apenas para dar uns exemplos, sua regex só funcionaria se os atributos `start`, `stop` e `channel` estivessem exatamente nesta ordem.

Se mudar a ordem dos atributos, não funciona mais. Se a tag estivesse espalhada por várias linhas, não funcionaria mais. Se ela estivesse comentada, também seria considerada pela regex (já o `DOMDocument` ignoraria corretamente a tag).

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) tem um exemplo mais detalhado (apesar de ser HTML, as mesmas preocupações se aplicam).

Enfim, regex é legal, mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

---

Só para não deixar incompleto, para pegar os resultados do `preg_match_all`, bastaria fazer:

```
if (preg_match_all('/<(\w+)\s+(start="(?<dt_con>.*?)".+stop="(?<ed_con>.*?)".+channel="(?<ch_name>.*?)".+\n)/i', $xml, $channels, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($channels as $match) {
        $nome = $match[1];
        $start = $match['dt_con'];
        $stop = $match['ed_con'];
        $channel = $match['ch_name'];

        // usar os valores...
    }
}
```

Como você usou grupos nomeados, basta usar os nomes (`dt_con`, `ed_con`, etc) para pegar os seus valores. Também modifiquei a regex para pegar o nome da tag.

Mas como já disse, esta regex é "ingênua" e propensa à falhas (todas já mencionadas acima e nos links já citados). Prefira usar `DOMDocument` ou qualquer outro *parser* de XML.