# Qual a melhor forma de pegar valores dentro de várias TAGs em vários arquivos HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex

Tenho várias páginas HTML, assim:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
    <title>TEXTO</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <link href="../Styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../Styles/page_styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
  <body id="a24" xml:lang="pt-BR" class="calibre">
        <div class="quadro-de-texto-b-sico">
            <h2 class="tit3" id="calibre_pb_0"><img alt="20" src="../Images/00025.jpeg" class="calibre7"/></h2>
            <p class="miolo-sem-ent"><em class="italico">Procure onde dói mais.</em></p>
            <p class="miolo">Bryce se esquivara de dizer a Athalar como o conselho da Rainha Víbora havia sido certeiro. Já tinha dado a ele sua lista de suspeitos... mas o anjo não havia perguntado sobre sua outra exigência.</p>
            <p class="miolo">Então, eis o que decidira fazer: compilar uma lista com cada um dos movimentos de Danika uma semana antes de sua morte. No entanto, no momento em que terminava de abrir a galeria para o dia de trabalho, no momento em que descia até a biblioteca para fazer a lista... a náusea a golpeara.</p>
            <p class="miolo">Então ela ligou o laptop e começou a esmiuçar os e-mails trocados com Maximus Tertian, seis semanas antes. Talvez encontrasse alguma ligação ali... ou, pelo menos, uma pista dos planos do vampiro para aquela noite.</p>
            <p class="miolo">A cada mensagem profissional e insípida que relia, porém, as lembranças dos últimos dias de Danika raspavam a porta vedada de sua mente. Sibilavam e sussurravam como espectros ameaçadores, e Bryce tentava ignorá-las, procurando se concentrar nos e-mails de Tertian, mas...</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de pegar valores dentro das tags do HTML.

Exemplo:

```html
<title>TEXTO</title>
```

Quero pegar apenas `TEXTO`.

```html
<p class="miolo-sem-ent"><em class="italico">Procure onde dói mais.</em></p>
```

Quero pegar apenas `Procure onde dói mais`.

Esse processo se repete em mais 10 páginas iguais a essa.

Já fiz alguma coisa do tipo:

```js
fs.readFile('../output/part0000.html', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
  const cutTab = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
  const clearText = cutTab.replace(/<p( [a-zA-Z]+="[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+">)|<p class="[a-zA-Z]+">|<em class="[a-zA-Z]+">|<\/em>|-|\s+/g, ' ');
  const clearSpace = clearText.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
  const endLine= cutTab.replace(/(<\/p>)/g, "</p>#@");

  const cutWord = clearSpace.split('#');
  
  console.log(clearSpace);
});
```

Mas dessa forma estou achando, que assim, terei muito trabalho.

Teria uma forma mais prática?
Converter para JSON, XML ou TXT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) (e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052), [aqui](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), e principalmente [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)), não use regex para ler/manipular/fazer *parsing* de HTML.

O ideal é usar bibliotecas específicas para HTML/XML. Vou dar um exemplo com o [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom), mas você pode pesquisar e usar outra, se quiser. Só para você ter uma ideia de como ficaria:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const fs = require('fs');

// ler o arquivo html
let html_file = fs.readFileSync('../output/part0000.html', 'utf-8');
// obter o document do arquivo
const document = new JSDOM(html_file).window.document;

// A partir do document, você pode buscar facilmente pelas tags
// Ex: procurando por todas as tags "p" ou "title"
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('p, title')) {
    console.log(element.textContent); // obtendo o texto da tag
}
```

Ou seja, como o jsdom é possível obter o `document` do HTML, e a partir dele é possível usar [seletores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) para buscar os elementos que você precisa.

Isso é interessante não só por ser mais simples do que regex, mas também por considerar vários casos que a regex não pega. Por exemplo, se tiver uma tag comentada:

```html
<!--
<p>estou dentro de um comentário</p>
-->
```

A sua regex vai pegar este `p` também, mas ele não deveria ser pego, por estar comentado. O código acima com jsdom já ignora os comentários corretamente. E o fato de poder fazer a busca com seletores facilita muito a busca (pois você pode buscar por nome de classe, id e outros atributos, e [todas as outras possibilidades que os seletores oferecem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) - fazer o equivalente com regex é muito mais complicado).

Este é só um exemplo, claro. Veja os links que estão no início para mais casos em que a regex falha (e até é possível fazer uma ou mais expressões regulares que tratam esses casos, mas é tão complicado que começa a não valer a pena - uma lib dedicada como o jsdom já trata esses casos para você).