# Filtrar bloco de busca utilizando regex

Tags: regex

Estou tentando realizar um filtro utilizando de Regex para buscar os resultados que estão dentro do option value. mas não consigo pegar dos selects separados.

quando utilizo a expressão : `<option value="(.+?)"` retorna de todos, quando na verdade quero apenas os do caso do "fromPort"

Tambem tentei da seguinte maneira, mas não resultando em nenhum dado encontrado     `(?<=select name="fromPort" class="form-inline">)\s*.*(?=select)`

```
    <select name="fromPort" class="form-inline">
        <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
        <option value="Philadelphia">Philadelphia</option>
        <option value="Boston">Boston</option>
        <option value="Portland">Portland</option>
        <option value="San Diego">San Diego</option>
        <option value="Mexico City">Mexico City</option>
        <option value="São Paolo">São Paolo</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <h2>Choose your destination city:</h2>
    <select name="toPort" class="form-inline">
        <option value="Buenos Aires">Buenos Aires</option>
        <option value="Rome">Rome</option>
        <option value="London">London</option>
        <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
        <option value="Dublin">Dublin</option>
        <option value="Cairo">Cairo</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Cada linguagem tem sua própria variante de sintaxe de expressões regulares, então sempre que o assunto é regex é importante informar em que linguagem está trabalhando. Analisar HTML com regex não algo recomendável, nesse trecho por exemplo se o autor do HTML fizer uma atualização trocando a ordem dos atributos teria que reescrever sua regex. Existem ferramentas de analise de HTML e XML ao montes na internet e dependendo da linguagem que esteja usando o parser de HTML pode estar embutido do framework da linguagem

Comment: na verdade, é para fins acadêmicos, não estou utilizando linguagem, estou trabalhando diretamente no regex101. Então gostaria de saber a possibilidade de fazer isso em regex, sei que é possivel, mas não consigo chegar a alguma conclusão..

Comment: No meio técnico e acadêmico analisar HTML com REGEX é considerado má prática. Por estar classificado como uma linguagem de tipo 2 na Hierarquia Chomsky o HTML deve ser analisado por uma máquina de estados DPDA com AST e pilha de estados e o REGEX não dá conta analisar de variações semântica. Veja esse texto [Analisando Html do jeito Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) se tiver dificuldades com o inglês o traduza para o português clicando com o botão direito e selecionando traduzir.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @AugustoVasques, irei ler o artigo.

Comment: Olá Willian, não precisa de regex para isso, se é uma string e esta usando JavaScript pode usar o [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), se for uma string no back-end com PHP pode usar o [DOMDocument::loadHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), se for Java pode usar a lib [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) ... se citar a linguagem que vai usar (e se é back-end ou front-end) posso sugerir um exemplo melhor, pois como o @AugustoVasques, regex poderá ter problemas com minimas "variantes" inesperadas

Comment: Usar um parser de html/xml é geralmente a melhor opção, como já disseram acima. Por exemplo, a regex da resposta abaixo é ingênua e falha se tiver dois `option` na mesma linha, ou um cujo fechamento esteja em outra linha, ou um deles comentado, ou se o `select` tiver outros atributos, ou se o `name` e `class` estiverem em outra ordem, etc. Qualquer variação mínima exigirá uma alteração na regex que nem sempre é trivial, e a tendência é que ela fique tão complicada que começa a não valer mais a pena. Leitura complementar: [aqui](/q/129557/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: E só pra citar mais alguns exemplos de porque não é bom usar regex para manipular HTML: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/509938/112052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar esse regex:

`<select name="fromPort" class="form\-inline">\n(?:.*?<option value="(.*?)">.*?<\/option>\n){1,}</select>`.

[Exemplo aqui.](http://regexr.com/5ta16)

O regex acima vai retornar o último option value da lista.

#### Aviso

Você não vai conseguir extrair esses valores usando apenas um regex, teria de ser no mínimo dois: um pra extrair todo o corpo do `select` e outro para extrair o valor dentro dos `options`. O motivo disso é que com um regex, ele vai encontrar **um** match para todo o corpo, porém você precisa capturar **vários** items.

Você só iria ter sucesso com um único regex se soubesse a quantidade de options e montar essa regex com essa quantidade de options, isto é, manualmente colocar o monte de options em seus respectivos grupos.

Se você acessar o link acima e duplicar a parte que busca o option (`(?:.*?<option value="(.*?)">.*?<\/option>\n)`), ele vai retornar apenas dois valores, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: No meu exemplo eu acabei usando o select do **toPort** rs.

Comment: Excelente, era basicamente essa a ideia que estava buscando!

Comment: Em vez de `{1,}`, basta usar `+` - de qualquer forma, usar regex para manipular HTML quase nunca é uma boa ideia (vide [meu comentário](/q/509859#comment936377_509859) na pergunta, além dos links indicados). E só como curiosidade, em C# [é possível capturar vários itens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection?view=net-5.0) quando um grupo de captura se repete (claro que a pergunta não citou nenhuma linguagem, mas enfim, não é algo impossível :-) Apenas não é suportado na maioria das linguagens/engines)