# Substituir o src de todas as tags img que tem imagens em Base 64

Tags: javascript, html, string, regex, replace

Estou consumindo uma API em que retorna uma string contendo um HTML.

Este HTML será usado como uma visualização da web em um aplicativo móvel, e contém tags `img` com `src` em Base 64.

Preciso alterar todos os `src` com Base 64 para uma imagem padrão (`default.png`). Qual regex eu poderia usar para fazer isso?

Exemplo do que recebo na request:

```html
<img src=\"data:image\/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAakAAACYCAYAAABefRbnAAAgAElEQVR4AeydBXRcR7KG9+2+t2\/hBTeJ4zh2bAccO2ZmZmZmZmYZZGZmkJmZmZmZSZJl5sSB3ay99c5Xo55cT2RbcgQzSuscnTtzp2\/f7urqou7+6w\/fBV+TkSuQmCC\" alt=\"\" />

<img src=\"data:image\/png;base64,FqT8XomvHz8iASWKq5HEADIS7dqmlRQvWEC2rVj6GHjxW6uG9eW111+X2J\/ElLffekv+d+PKE2VwdNtmefPNN2Xp9zOfeI2\/dmCC\" alt=\"\" />
```

Gostaria de usar um replace nessa string para identificar os `src` com Base 64 e deixar como:

```html
<img src=\"default.png" alt=\"\" />

<img src=\"default.png" alt=\"\" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Não use regex

Conforme já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (e em muitos outros lugares, [basta procurar](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+it+bad+parse+html+with+regex)), regex não é a melhor ferramenta para manipular HTML (leia os links para entender os motivos).

Primeiro vou mostrar a solução mais simples, sem regex. E depois mostrar uma com regex pra você ver como não é o ideal.

---

### Sem regex

Você pode manipular a string diretamente usando um elemento `template`, pois na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) diz que ele é um "mecanismo para conter HTML que não será renderizado imediatamente na página". E parece ser exatamente o que você quer fazer: primeiro quer manipular o HTML e só depois (opcionalmente) você pode colocá-lo na página.

Seria assim:

```js
// criando um HTML com outros elementos, inclusive uma imagem que não tem src com Base 64
const string = `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAakAAACYCAYAAABefRbnAAAgAElEQVR4AeydBXRcR7KG9+2+t2/hBTeJ4zh2bAccO2ZmZmZmZmYZZGZmkJmZmZmZSZJl5sSB3ay99c5Xo55cT2RbcgQzSuscnTtzp2/f7urqou7+6w/fBV+TkSuQmCC" alt="">
<p>outra tag</p>
<img src="nao_sou_base64.png">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,FqT8XomvHz8iASWKq5HEADIS7dqmlRQvWEC2rVj6GHjxW6uG9eW111+X2J/ElLffekv+d+PKE2VwdNtmefPNN2Xp9zOfeI2/dmCC" alt="">`;

// cria o template e coloca a string nele
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = string;
// pega as imagens que tem src com Base 64 e troca para o valor default
for (const img of template.content.querySelectorAll('img[src^="data:image/png;base64,"]')) {
    img.src = 'default.png';
}

// mostra como ficou o HTML
console.log(template.innerHTML);
```

Ao setar o `innerHTML` do `template`, é feito o *parsing* da string, e o `template` conterá os respectivos elementos na forma de um [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), que depois você pode usar para buscar os elementos que quer.

No caso, eu busquei por todas as imagens cujo `src` seja Base 64: o [seletor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `img[src^="data:image/png;base64,"]` busca pelas tags `img` cujo atributo `src` comece com `data:image/png;base64,`. Depois, basta trocar o `src` desses elementos e mostrar como ficou o HTML final.

O código acima imprime:

```html
<img src="default.png" alt="">
<p>outra tag</p>
<img src="nao_sou_base64.png">
<img src="default.png" alt="">
```

Repare como a imagem que não era Base 64 permaneceu intacta.

E uma vez tendo o HTML modificado, você pode fazer o que quiser com ele. Por exemplo, se quiser adicionar os elementos na página, bastaria fazer:

```js
// adicionar elementos na página
for (const elemento of template.content.childNodes)
    document.body.appendChild(elemento.cloneNode(true));

// Ou, se quiser colocar tudo dentro de algum elemento qualquer
elemento.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
```

---

### Com regex

A versão simplista e ingênua com regex é:

```js
const string = `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAakAAACYCAYAAABefRbnAAAgAElEQVR4AeydBXRcR7KG9+2+t2/hBTeJ4zh2bAccO2ZmZmZmZmYZZGZmkJmZmZmZSZJl5sSB3ay99c5Xo55cT2RbcgQzSuscnTtzp2/f7urqou7+6w/fBV+TkSuQmCC" alt="">
<p>outra tag</p>
<img src="nao_sou_base64.png">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,FqT8XomvHz8iASWKq5HEADIS7dqmlRQvWEC2rVj6GHjxW6uG9eW111+X2J/ElLffekv+d+PKE2VwdNtmefPNN2Xp9zOfeI2/dmCC" alt="">`;

console.log(string.replace(/<img src="data:image\/png;base64,[a-zA-Z0-9+\/=]+"/g, '<img src="default.png"'));
```

Eu disse que é "simplista e ingênua" porque ela confia cegamente que as tags sempre serão `<img src="etc...`. Se tiver qualquer atributo entre `img` e `src` (por exemplo, `<img id="bla" class="whatever" src="etc...`), já não funciona mais.

Se o atributo tiver em outra linha (o que é perfeitamente válido em HTML) também não funciona mais:

```html
<img
  src="etc..."
```

Se a tag estiver dentro de um comentário, a regex não ignora. E por aí vai, HTML tem uma série de variações possíveis, e embora seja possível resolver a maioria delas, a regex ficará cada vez mais complicada (só a que detecta comentários, por exemplo, [é um "pequeno monstro"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42097865)) e não vale a pena. Já o código acima com `template` funciona para todos esses casos, sem precisar modificar nada.

Comment: Muito obrigado, as duas opções funcionaram, mas vou optar pela primeira como recomendado. Estou estudando regex, então estou tentando aprender como ele funciona. Poderia me tirar uma dúvida se nao for muito incomodo?: no replace do RegEx, se eu quisesse dar o replace apenas no primeiro item que ele encontrar ao invés de todos, o que eu adicionaria no regex? Pergunto pois nunca entendi como dar replace em apenas no primeiro item, ele sempre faz o replace geral. Desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: @GustavoLopes Se tem outra dúvida, sugiro [fazer outra pergunta](/questions/ask), pois aí ela fica visível na página principal e mais gente pode ver, o que aumenta as chances de ser respondida (aqui nos comentários, só eu vou ver). **Mas antes de perguntar**, [faça uma busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) pra ver se ela já não foi respondida. Mas se for para estudar, eu sugiro seguir algum tutorial - eu gosto bastante [desse](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [desse](https://rexegg.com/)

Comment: @GustavoLopes  Mas no caso, pra substituir apenas um, retire o `g` que tem depois da `/` (com o "g" ele substitui tudo, sem o "g", só a primeira ocorrência)